# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my component's render function I have:

```
render() {
    const items = ['EN', 'IT', 'FR', 'GR', 'RU'].map((item) => {
      return (<li onClick={this.onItemClick.bind(this, item)} key={item}>{item}</li>);
    });
    return (
      <div>
        ...
                <ul>
                  {items}
                </ul>
         ...
      </div>
    );
  }
```

everything renders fine, however when clicking the `<li>` element I receive the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React
>   child (found: object with keys {dispatchConfig, dispatchMarker,
>   nativeEvent, target, currentTarget, type, eventPhase, bubbles,
>   cancelable, timeStamp, defaultPrevented, isTrusted, view, detail,
>   screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey,
>   metaKey, getModifierState, button, buttons, relatedTarget, pageX,
>   pageY, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, _dispatchListeners,
>   _dispatchIDs}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from
>   the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Welcome`.

If I change to `this.onItemClick.bind(this, item)` to `(e) => onItemClick(e, item)` inside the map function everything works as expected.

If someone could explain what I am doing wrong and explain why do I get this error, would be great

UPDATE 1:
onItemClick function is as follows and removing this.setState results in error disappearing.

```
onItemClick(e, item) {
    this.setState({
      lang: item,
    });
}
```

But I cannot remove this line as I need to update state of this component

Comment: So how `this.onItemClick` is implemented?

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for replying, I updated the question, and yes it seems that   the problem is in this.setState(), but why does it throw this error? :(

Comment: Is there a syntax  error in setState? An extra comma? Might not fix the error, but just found it.

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli comma is a matter of preference, my eslint forces me to do that, but removing it does not help, thanks for reply

Comment: I got this error when I forgot curly braces around a variable that had become a state-ful object from local variable after adding it to state in refactor.

Comment: this can also happen if you put `async` on the function component

Comment: Because of the way `bind` works, the parameters to your event handler should be reversed - `onItemClick(e, item)` -> `onItemClick(item, e)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56032113/9260161

Comment: As a good practice do not use `bind` inside the render method. When you use `bind` inside the render function, what happens is when the render method get invoked a new instance of the `onItemClick` will be created. So either you can use arrow function syntax or bind your methods in the constructor. You can find more details in the official guide https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html.

Comment: Thanks @PetrosKyriakou. I made my render() method async by mistake. You rock!

Comment: @phatmann happy to help!

Answer (score 546):

I was having this error and it turned out to be that I was unintentionally including an Object in my JSX code that I had expected to be a string value:

```
return (
    <BreadcrumbItem href={routeString}>
        {breadcrumbElement}
    </BreadcrumbItem>
)
```

`breadcrumbElement` used to be a string but due to a refactor had become an Object. Unfortunately, React's error message didn't do a good job in pointing me to the line where the problem existed. I had to follow my stack trace all the way back up until I recognized the "props" being passed into a component and then I found the offending code.

You'll need to either reference a property of the object that is a string value or convert the Object to a string representation that is desirable. One option might be `JSON.stringify` if you actually want to see the contents of the Object.

Comment: So, if you do have an object, how would you go about transforming it into something desirable?

Comment: You'll need to either reference a property of the object that is a string value or convert the Object to a string representation that is desirable. One option might be JSON.stringify if you actually want to see the contents of the Object.

Comment: Encountered same error and this explaination solved my issue. 1 UP for this. :)

Comment: Ahh, I had the same issue of the error message pointing at the wrong line - it said the error was in this.setState({items: items}) when really it blew up further down where I was trying to display that variable using {this.state.items}. JSON.stringify fixed it!

Comment: For future readers: No don't convert to string. Do this instead: const Lcomponent = this.whateverReturnsObject(); then in render(){ return <Lcomponent /> } Thats its.

Comment: I had a date to show. When I used moment to format it to string, error cleared

Comment: JSON.stringify does not work for cyclic data types like arrays, does anyone has any idea how to show those?

Comment: it helps to use ternary statements in your components' selective logic, see my answer to a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59108109/1483143

Comment: I was so confused since the exception was being thrown during my `useState` call.

Answer (score 134):

So I got this error when trying to display the `createdAt` property which is a Date object.  If you concatenate `.toString()` on the end like this, it will do the conversion and eliminate the error.  Just posting this as a possible answer in case anyone else ran into the same problem:

```
{this.props.task.createdAt.toString()}
```

Comment: Bingo!  I had this problem but was thrown off track because the table that was displaying it would load (and reload) just fine.  React would only throw the `objects are not valid` invariant violation when I **added** a row.  Turns out I was converting the Date() object to a string before persisting it so only my new rows had objects for the created date. :(  Learn from my wayward example people!

Comment: a more broad approach is to use ternary statements in your components' selective logic, see my answer to a similar problem I kept encountering here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59108109/1483143

Comment: I definitely had this problem. I was using a React Grid from DevExtreme and it didn't like my date property in my object array. Converting it to a string using .toString() helped right away.

Answer (score 62):

I just got the same error but due to a different mistake: I used double braces like:

```
{{count}}
```

to insert the value of `count` instead of the correct:

```
{count}
```

which the compiler turned into `{{count: count}}`, i.e. trying to insert an Object as a React child.

Comment: what {{}} are meant for/

Comment: @MuneemHabib it's just ES6 syntax. React needs one pair of `{}`. The inner pair is treat as ES6 code. In ES6, `{count}` is the same as `{count: count}`. So when you type `{{count}}`, that is exactly the same as `{ {count: count} }`.

Comment: Had this error -- this was the problem.  In assigning my variable to state in the constructor I had `this.state = {navMenuItems: {navMenu}};` ... which basically turned my JSX `navMenu` into a generic object.  Changing to `this.state = {navMenuItems: navMenu};` got rid of the unintentional 'cast' to `Object` and fixed the issue.

Comment: I guess you came from Angular world :D

Comment: bouncing around front end technologies, this was my problem. It's so obvious now! Thanks

Answer (score 34):

Just thought I would add to this as I had the same problem today, turns out that it was because I was returning just the function, when I wrapped it in a `<div>` tag it started working, as below

```
renderGallery() {
  const gallerySection = galleries.map((gallery, i) => {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  });
  return (
    {gallerySection}
  );
}
```

The above caused the error. I fixed the problem by changing the `return()` section to:

```
return (
  <div>
    {gallerySection}
  </div>
);
```

...or simply:

```
return gallerySection
```

Comment: or you can simply use `return gallerySection` if you want to avoid an extra `div`

Comment: Returning `gallerySection` instead of `<div>{gallerySection}</div>` helped me.

Answer (score 30):

React child(singular) **should be type of [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) data type** not object or **it could be JSX tag(which is not in our case)**. Use Proptypes package in development to make sure validation happens.

Just a quick code snippet(JSX) comparision to represent you with idea :

1. Error : With object being passed into child

   ```
   <div>
   {/* item is object with user's name and its other details on it */}
    {items.map((item, index) => {
     return <div key={index}>
   --item object invalid as react child--->>>{item}</div>;
    })}
   </div>
   ```
2. Without error : With object's property(**which should be primitive, i.e. a string value or integer value**) being passed into child.

   ```
   <div>
    {/* item is object with user's name and its other details on it */}
     {items.map((item, index) => {
      return <div key={index}>
   --note the name property is primitive--->{item.name}</div>;
     })}
   </div>
   ```

TLDR; (From the source below) : Make sure all of the items you're rendering in JSX are primitives and not objects when using React. This error usually happens because a function involved in dispatching an event has been given an unexpected object type (i.e passing an object when you should be passing a string) or part of the JSX in your component is not referencing a primitive (i.e. this.props vs this.props.name).

Source - codingbismuth.com

Comment: this link no longer works, however I find the structure of your answer to be the most informative in my use case. This error is produceable in both web and react native environments, and often occures as a lifecycle error when attempting to .map() an array of objects within a component using async lifecycle.

I came across this thread while using react native react-native-scrollview

Comment: Glad, that you find it useful and thanks for flagging link issue.

Comment: This helped me. Return a property rather than an object: `return <p>{item.whatever}</p>;`

Answer (score 21):

Mine had to do with forgetting the curly braces around props being sent to a presentational component:

Before:

```
const TypeAheadInput = (name, options, onChange, value, error) => {
```

After

```
const TypeAheadInput = ({name, options, onChange, value, error}) => {
```

Comment: My problem was most similar to yours, so applying your solution helped me.  +1 and Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

I too was getting this "Objects are not valid as a React child" error and for me the cause was due to calling an asynchronous function in my JSX.  See below.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    showHello = async () => {
        const response = await someAPI.get("/api/endpoint");

        // Even with response ignored in JSX below, this JSX is not immediately returned, 
        // causing "Objects are not valid as a React child" error.
        return (<div>Hello!</div>);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.showHello()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What I learned is that asynchronous rendering is not supported in React.  The React team is working on a solution [as documented here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).

Comment: what you should instead do is to update state as the data comes in, and then render the components using state values

Comment: what you should instead do is to update state as the data comes in, and then render the components using state values

Comment: This helped in my case

Answer (score 16):

Mine had to do with unnecessarily putting curly braces around a variable holding a HTML element inside the return statement of the render() function. This made React treat it as an object rather than an element.

```
render() {
  let element = (
    <div className="some-class">
      <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    {element}
  )
}
```

Once I removed the curly braces from the element, the error was gone, and the element was rendered correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Remove the curly braces from the element works for me too!

Answer (score 8):

For anybody using Firebase with Android, this only breaks Android.  My iOS emulation ignores it.

And as posted by Apoorv Bankey above.

Anything above Firebase V5.0.3, for Android, atm is a bust.  Fix:

```
npm i --save firebase@5.0.3
```

Confirmed numerous times here
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/871

Comment: For anybody attempting the solution proposed by KNDheeraj below, 

****
1
down vote
If in case your using Firebase any of the files within your project. Then just place that import firebase statement at the end!!

I know this sounds crazy but try it!!
****************

I did try it and this is not a solution for iOS but for Android on Windows only.

Answer (score 8):

I also have the same problem but my mistake is so stupid. I was trying to access object directly.

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        name:'xyz',
        age:10
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                // this is what I am using which gives the error
                <p>I am inside the {state}.</p> 

                //Correct Way is

                <p>I am inside the {this.state.name}.</p> 
            </div>
        );
    }                                                                             

}
```

Comment: wow this helped I don't understand why you why you have to access object individuals

Answer (score 8):

Typically this pops up because you don't destructure properly. Take this code for example:

```
const Button = text => <button>{text}</button>

const SomeForm = () => (
  <Button text="Save" />
)
```

We're declaring it with the `= text =>` param. But really, React is expecting this to be an all-encompassing `props` object.

So we should really be doing something like this:

```
const Button = props => <button>{props.text}</button>

const SomeForm = () => (
  <Button text="Save" />
)
```

Notice the difference? The `props` param here could be named anything (`props` is just the convention that matches the nomenclature), React is just expecting an object with keys and vals.

With [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) you can do, and will frequently see, something like this:

```
const Button = ({ text }) => <button>{text}</button>

const SomeForm = () => (
  <Button text="Save" />
)
```

...which works.

Chances are, anyone stumbling upon this just accidentally declared their component's props param without destructuring.

Comment: This should appear as the correct answer, newbie mistake ;)

Answer (score 6):

### Just remove the curly braces in the return statement.

Before:

```
render() {
    var rows = this.props.products.map(product => <tr key={product.id}><td>{product.name}</td><td>{product.price}</td></tr>);
    return {rows}; // unnecessary
}
```

After:

```
render() {
    var rows = this.props.products.map(product => <tr key={product.id}><td>{product.name}</td><td>{product.price}</td></tr>);
    return rows; // add this
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This was my code :

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: null,
      getDatacall : null
    }
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this)
  }
  getData() {
  //   if (this.state.getDatacall === false) {
    sleep(4000)
    returnData("what is the time").then(value => this.setState({value, getDatacall:true}))
    // }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    sleep(4000)

    this.getData()
  }
  render() {
    this.getData()
    sleep(4000)
    console.log(this.state.value)
    return (
      <p> { this.state.value } </p>
    )
  }
}
```

when I ran into the error in question. I had to change it to :

```js
 render() {
    this.getData()
    sleep(4000)
    console.log(this.state.value)
    return (
      <p> { JSON.stringify(this.state.value) } </p>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was i forgot to return a html element frm the render function and i was returning an object . What i did was i just wrapped the {items} with a html element - a simple div like below

```html
<ul>{items}</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem because I didn't put the `props` in the curly braces.

```
export default function Hero(children, hero ) {
    return (
        <header className={hero}>
            {children}
        </header>
    );
}
```

So if your code is similar to the above one then you will get this error.
To resolve this just put curly braces around the `props`.

```
export default function Hero({ children, hero }) {
    return (
        <header className={hero}>
            {children}
        </header>
    );
}
```

Comment: I did not say it wasn't. I think your answer looks better with the indentation. If you disagree please feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error, I changed this

`export default withAlert(Alerts)`

to this

`export default withAlert()(Alerts)`.

In older versions the former code was ok , but in later versions it throws an error. So use the later code to avoid the errror.

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason you imported firebase. Then try running `npm i --save firebase@5.0.3`. This is because firebase break react-native, so running this will fix it.

Answer (score 4):

### Just remove the `async` keyword in the component.

```
const Register = () => {
```

*No issues after this.*

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I added a async to my child function component and encountered this error. Don't use async with child component.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error any time I was calling async on a renderItem function in my FlatList.

I had to create a new function to set my Firestore collection to my state before calling said state data inside my FlatList.

Comment: I got the same caused by an async function called by the navigation

Answer (score 3):

My case is quite common when using reduce but it was not shared here so I posted it.

Normally, if your array looks like this:

`[{ value: 1}, {value: 2}]`

And you want to render the sum of `value` in this array. JSX code looks like this

```
<div>{array.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.value + curr.value)}</div>
```

The problem happens when your array has only one item, eg: `[{value: 1}]`.
(Typically, this happens when your array is the response from server so you can not guarantee numbers of items in that array)

The `reduce` function returns the element itself when array has only one element, in this case it is `{value: 1}` (an object), it causes the **Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child** error.

Answer (score 2):

You were just using the keys of object, instead of the whole object!

More details can be found here: https://github.com/gildata/RAIO/issues/48

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class SCT extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            data: this.props.data,
            new_data: {}
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let new_data = this.state.data;
        console.log(`new_data`, new_data);
        this.setState(
            {
                new_data: Object.assign({}, new_data)
            }
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                this.state.data = {JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}
                <hr/>
                <div style={{color: 'red'}}>
                    {this.state.new_data.name}<br />
                    {this.state.new_data.description}<br />
                    {this.state.new_data.dependtables}<br />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

SCT.propTypes = {
    test: PropTypes.string,
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export {SCT};
export default SCT;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If using stateless components, follow this kind of format:

```
const Header = ({pageTitle}) => (
  <h1>{pageTitle}</h1>
);
export {Header};
```

This seemed to work for me

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firebase and seeing this error, it's worth to check if you're importing it right. As of version 5.0.4 you have to import it like this:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
import '@firebase/auth';
import '@firebase/database';
import '@firebase/storage';
```

Yes, I know. I lost 45 minutes on this, too.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem with firebase (5.9.2) :)

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you try to render objects as child elements, you can find out the root cause by looking for below scenarios.

1. Check if you are using any double braces in JSX - `<span>{{value}}</span>` and change it to `<span>{value}</span>` (I did this mistake since I just moved from Angular to React).
2. Check of return statements wrapped around braces like below and remove it.

   ```
    render() {
      let element = (
       <span>text</span>
      );

      return (
       {element}  // => Remove this extra brace
      )
    }
   ```
3. Check any other unintentional way you are using object in the JSX

   ```
    let nestedObjected = {
       a : '1',
       b : {
          c: '2'
       }
    };
    {Object.keys(nestedObjected).map((key) => {
       return (
           <div>
              <span>{nestedObjected[key]}</span>  // This will cause issue since it will resolve to an object
           </div>
       );
     })}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I just put myself through a really silly version of this error, which I may as well share here for posterity.

I had some JSX like this:

```
...
{
  ...
  <Foo />
  ...
}
...
```

I needed to comment this out to debug something. I used the keyboard shortcut in my IDE, which resulted in this:

```
...
{
  ...
  { /* <Foo /> */ }
  ...
}
...
```

Which is, of course, invalid -- objects are not valid as react children!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add another solution to this list.

Specs:

- "react": "^16.2.0",
- "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
- "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
- "react-scripts": "^1.0.17",
- "redux": "^3.7.2"

I encountered the same error:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object
>   with keys {XXXXX}). If you meant to render a collection of children,
>   use an array instead.

This was my code:

```
let payload = {
      guess: this.userInput.value
};

this.props.dispatch(checkAnswer(payload));
```

Solution:

```
  // let payload = {
  //   guess: this.userInput.value
  // };

this.props.dispatch(checkAnswer(this.userInput.value));
```

The problem was occurring because the payload was sending the item as an object. When I removed the payload variable and put the userInput value into the dispatch everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If in case your using Firebase any of the files within your project.
Then just place that import firebase statement at the end!!

I know this sounds crazy but try it!!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, in my case, 
I update the **redux** state, and new data parameters did not match old parameters, So when I want to access some parameters it through this Error,

Maybe this experience help someone

Comment: In my case, (Django) ListSerializer and CreateSerializer return same fields and some of them (it's up to your project) are just read-only fields, So fetch Once and whenever create new data just simply update the redux state

Answer (score 1):

My issue was simple when i faced the following error:

```
objects are not valid as a react child (found object with keys {...}
```

was just that I was passing an object with keys specified in the error while trying to render the object directly in a component using {object} expecting it to be a string

```
object: {
    key1: "key1",
    key2: "key2"
}
```

while rendering on a React Component, I used something like below

```
render() {
    return this.props.object;
}
```

but it should have been

```
render() {
    return this.props.object.key1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this has just happened to me...

I wrote:

```
{response.isDisplayOptions &&
{element}
}
```

Placing it inside a div fixed it:

```
{response.isDisplayOptions &&
    <div>
        {element}
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Found: object with keys

Which means you passing something is a key-value. So you need to modify your handler:

from

```
onItemClick(e, item) {
   this.setState({
     lang: item,
   });
}
```

to

```
onItemClick({e, item}) {
  this.setState({
    lang: item,
  });
}
```

You missed out the braces (`{}`).

Comment: can't believe this was the problem

Comment: im also wonder. still haven't figure it out what issue is cause this

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because of a dynamic array which had to  be injected at runtime.

I just added the null checks for object and it worked fine.

**Before:**

```
...
render(
...
    <div> {props.data.roles[0]} </div>
...
);
```

**After:**

```
...
let items = (props && props.data && props.data.roles)? props.data.roles: [];
render(
...
    <div> {items[i]} </div>
...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are printing Object/ Arrays in the console.log then also this error comes. Make sure you add JSON. stringify if you want to do console.log for objects/Arrays

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem mostly happens because of forgetting curly braces, which leads that JavaScript doesn't realize all elements as an array. In my case, it was like this:

```
function DynamicRow(id, name, avatar, email, salary, date, status){
```

and the solution:

```
function DynamicRow({id, name, avatar, email, salary, date, status}){
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of using Firebase, if it doesn't work by putting at the end of `import` statements then you can try to put that inside one of the life-cycle method, that is, you can put it inside `componentWillMount()`.

```
componentWillMount() {
    const firebase = require('firebase');
    firebase.initializeApp({
        //Credentials
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child` happened to me when using a component that needed a `renderItem` props, like:

```
renderItem={this.renderItem}
```

and my mistake was to make my `renderItem` method `async`.

Answer (score 0):

My error was because of writing it this way:

```
props.allinfo.map((stuff, i)=>{
  return (<p key={i}> I am {stuff} </p>)
})
```

instead of:

```
props.allinfo.map((stuff, i)=>{
  return (<p key={i}> I am {stuff.name} </p>)
})
```

It meant I was trying to render object instead of the value within it.

edit: this is for react not native.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was very particular: in my `.env` file, I put a comment in the line that had my api url:

```
API_URL=https://6ec1259f.ngrok.io #comment
```

I'd get the `Invariant violation` error when trying to log in/sign up, as the api url was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    throw new Error(<p>An error occured</p>)
}catch(e){
    return (e)
}
```

The above code produced the error, I then rewrote it like this:

```
try{
    throw(<p>An error occured</p>)
}catch(e){
    return (e)
}
```

Take note of the removal of **new Error()** in the try block...

A better way to write the code in order to avoid this error message **Expected an object to be thrown no-throw-literal** is to pass a string into **throw new Error()** instead of JSX and return JSX in your catch block, something like this:

```
try{
    throw new Error("An error occurred")
}catch(e){
    return (
        <p>{e.message}</p>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What's happening is the onClick function you are trying to implement gets executed immediately.
2. As our code is not HTML it is javascript so it is interpreted as a function execution.
3. onClick function takes a function as argument not an function execution.

`const items = ['EN', 'IT', 'FR', 'GR', 'RU'].map((item) => {
      return (<li onClick={(e) => onItemClick(e, item)} key={item}>{item}</li>);
    });`

this will define an onClick function on List Item that will get executed after clicking on it not as soon as our component renders.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, as others have mentioned previously in this thread, in React JSX `props.children` [cannot be of type Object](https://react-legacy.netlify.com/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#jsx-children).  **This is NOT the *root cause* for the issue in your specific question.**

If you carefully read the error text, you will see that React has produced the error while trying to render an Object that matches the signature of a [`SyntheticEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html):

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {dispatchConfig, dispatchMarker, nativeEvent, target, currentTarget, type, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelable, timeStamp, defaultPrevented, isTrusted, view, detail, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, metaKey, getModifierState, button, buttons, relatedTarget, pageX, pageY, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, _dispatchListeners, _dispatchIDs}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of Welcome.
```

However, one wonders why you are trying to render a `SyntheticEvent`, and this is where the real answer to your question resides.  You obviously have no intention of rendering a `SyntheticEvent`, but you've got your **event handler parameters out of order**.

In your `render` method, you are binding the `onItemClick` event handler to the `this` of your class component and passing in `item` as an argument:

```
render() {
    const items = ['EN', 'IT', 'FR', 'GR', 'RU'].map((item) => {
      return (<li onClick={this.onItemClick.bind(this, item)} key={item}>{item}</li>);
    });
// ...
```

According to the documentation for [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Syntax), **all arguments passed after the `thisArg` are *prepended* to any arguments subsequently passed when the target function is later invoked**:

> arg1, arg2, ...
>
> Arguments to prepend to arguments provided to the
>   bound function when invoking the target function.

If we then look at the event handler, we see that the parameter `e` is listed before the parameter `item`.

```
onItemClick(e, item) {
    this.setState({
      lang: item,
    });
}
```

**When `onItemClick(e, item)` is invoked, the `item` passed in during the `bind` invocation will *precede* the triggering `event`, so parameter `e` will be set to the mapped and bound `item`, and parameter `item` will be set to the `event`.**

When `setState` is called, `lang` will be set to the `SyntheticEvent` representing the triggering `onClick` event, and when you try to render the value in `this.state.lang` elsewhere, you will receive the Invariant Violation error you've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a valid JSX element. In my case I assigned a component to an object.

```
const AwesomeButtonComponent = () => <button>AwesomeButton</button>
const next = {
  link: "http://awesomeLink.com",
  text: "Awesome text",
  comp: AwesomeButtonComponent
}
```

Somewhere else in my Code I wanted to dynamically assign that button.

```
return (
  <div>
    {next.comp ? next.comp : <DefaultAwesomeButtonComp/>}
  </div>
)
```

I solve this by declaring a JSX comp which I initialized via the props comp.

```
const AwesomeBtnFromProps = next.comp
return (
  <div>
    {next.comp ? <AwesomeBtnFromProps/> : <DefaultAwesomeButtonComp/>}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error rendering something in a ternary operator. 
What I did:

```
render(){
  const bar = <div>asdfasdf</div>
  return ({this.state.foo ? {bar} : <div>blahblah</div>})
}
```

Turns out it should be bar without the brackets, like:

```
render(){
  const bar = <div>asdfasdf</div>
  return ({this.state.foo ? bar : <div>blahblah</div>})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who mentioned `Stringify()` and `toString()` as solution, I will say that worked for me but we have to understand the problem and why did it occur. In my code it was simple issue. I had 2 buttons which call same function but one button was not passing the argument to that function properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 {items && items.title ? items.title : 'No item'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the error, react considered you are trying to display the object of 'li', but you really don't.

You used 'bind' method in the wrong place. When you use bind in the 'li', 'this' will be considered the object of 'li'. Since object has an extra keyword(onItemClick), henceforth it's not a react tag, and it's a js object with the properties those react li tag, has.

If you use the 'bind' method in constructor of Component
there will be no problem. But in your usecase this is impossible. So the "(e) => onItemClick(e, item)" is the best try.

Ignore my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that when you render the li you are passing not passing the function to the component you are calling it so it will call it once the li is rendered for that you need to pass the reference to the function not calling it to do that you ether write it like this if there was no argument to pass

```
onClick={this.onItemClick.bind}
```

or like this if there were arguments to pass

```
onClick={()=>this.onItemClick.bind(this, item)}
```

in this case it will create an anonymous function an pass it's reference

Answer (score 0):

Well, I spent half day trying to solve this

I wanted to show an array depending on if a user was logged in

this is what my code looked like
`return ({  userLogged ? userLoggedCart : cartItems } .map((item)=>{ return //irrelevant code}))`
but this was wrong, if your code looks like this you got to change it to

`if (userLogged){ return ( userLoggedCart.map((item)=>{ return //your code }))}  else { cartItems.map((item)=>{ return // your code })}`

Answer (score 0):

As I experienced same, besides adding "__html" to mark it, I resolved by putting marked HTML into a span with attribute "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" like below:

```
  createMarkup(innerHtml){
    return {__html: innerHtml};
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={
      this.createMarkup(this.props.details.entryContent)}/>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have placed 'async' in front of a functional component (either a wrapper for a jest & react-testing-library test or just a plain old functional component) like this:

```
const MockComponent = async () => {
  <Provider>
    <ComponentImGoingToTest />
  </Provider>
}
```

And you're expecting to be able to render it like this:

```
<MockComponent />
```

then two things:

1. You don't understand the implications of what async does.
2. Because of that keyword, calling your wrapper function will invoke a promise (which is an object), instead of the expected React functions that JSX boils down to.

Answer (score 0):

I got this "not valid as a React child" error because I passed an object as a prop from a parent component, and then I tried to render a property of that object as a string, when it was actually a Date. Rendering that as a string instead removed this  error.

Answer (score 0):

So I had an array with JSX elements `[h1, h3, div, null, div]` properly declared for instance `<h1 key={someh1key}>content</h1>` on that list etc. I go to render it in a form:

```
const myform = (<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>{mytds}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" onClick={(event) => history.push("/")}>Cancel</button>
        </form>);
```

and got the error: `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {mytds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

There are some solutions to this problem:

1. for me it was: **wrap the list in a Fragment** because a Fragment lets you render multiple elements, of different types, so a fragment was what I needed around the list. `<>{mytds}</>`.
2. Sometimes, your array just has data, but no JSX elements. In that case you will also see this error. You can avoid it by using something like: `array.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{item}</div>);` will work and get rid of the error, **though React recommends using unique keys and only using the index as a last resort.**

Above works because it will produce an array of React JSX Elements all of the same type with unique keys.

Now the form looks like this:

```
const myform = (<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}><>{mytds}</>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" onClick={(event) => history.push("/")}>Cancel</button>
        </form>);
```

I came across this: [Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428879/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-if-you-meant-to-render-a-collection-of-c?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) so this might be a duplicate question.

This was also helpful, but still did not answer the question. [https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child/#:~:text=Another%20common%20cause%20of%20the,a%20valid%20React%20child%20element](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child/#:%7E:text=Another%20common%20cause%20of%20the,a%20valid%20React%20child%20element).

Answer (score -3):

Thanks to [a comment by zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child/33118025#comment54048780_33117449), I was able to notice my stupid mistake:

I had `onItemClick(e, item)` when I should have had `onItemClick(item, e)`.