# React Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: '',
            loading: true
        }
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        const newsfeedURL = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/streetlife-coding-challenge/newsfeed.json';
        $.get(newsfeedURL, function(result) {
            this.setState({
                data: JSON.parse(result),
                loading: false
            });
            console.log(typeof this.state.data.messages);
        }.bind(this));
    }
    render () {
      let content;
      if (this.state.loading === false && this.state.data.messages) {
        content = Object.keys(this.state.data.messages).map(key => {
         return <div key={key}>Key: {key}, Value: {this.state.data.messages[key]}</div>;
        })
      } else { 
        content = ''; // whatever you want it to be while waiting for data
      }
      return (
        <div>
          {content}
        </div>
      )
    }
}


ReactDom.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

but I am getting the following error:

*Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {body, attachments, videos, topics, updated_at, id, subject, downvotes, author, posted_at, comments, user_vote, upvotes, status, tags, locations, track_impact, user_is_following, comments_count}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `App`.*

I had a look at this answer but it doesn't help in my case: [Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your div your are trying to render `Value: {this.state.data.messages[key]}` which is an object. You can't render Objects directly using React's JSX. What you can render however are some of the actual primitive data types held in this object (e.g. strings, numbers), for example `Value: {this.state.data.messages[key].body}` will render the string value held at the `body` property of the object. Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/bwowxP

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: '',
            loading: true
        }
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        const newsfeedURL = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/streetlife-coding-challenge/newsfeed.json';
        $.get(newsfeedURL, function(result) {
            this.setState({
                data: JSON.parse(result),
                loading: false
            });
            console.log(typeof this.state.data.messages);
        }.bind(this));
    }
    render () {
      let content;
      if (this.state.loading === false && this.state.data.messages) {
        content = Object.keys(this.state.data.messages).map(key => {
         console.log(this.state.data.messages[key])
         return <div key={key}><b>Key: {key},</b> Value: {this.state.data.messages[key].body}</div>;
        })
      } else { 
        content = ''; // whatever you want it to be while waiting for data
      }
      return (
        <div>
          {content}
        </div>
      )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: '',
            loading: true
        }
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        
        const newsfeedURL = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/streetlife-coding-challenge/newsfeed.json';
                $.get(newsfeedURL, function(result) {
                    this.setState({
                        data: result,
                        loading: false
                    });
                }.bind(this));
    }
    render () {
      let content;
      if (this.state.loading === false && this.state.data.messages) {
        content = this.state.data.messages.map((ele,key) => {
         return <div key={key}>id: {this.state.data.messages[key].id}</div>;
        })
      } else { 
        content = ''; // whatever you want it to be while waiting for data
      }
      return (
        <div>
          {content}
        </div>
      )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```