# Objects are not valid as a React child(In mobile phone of android 4.4 for react 15.6.1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The whole error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createF...<omitted>...`.

I can't find the exact location of this error, it just makes an error in the react-dom, so how can I debug and find out this error?

Comment: First, find out the exact location of the error. make your packing utils (webpack or whatever) add sourcemap

Comment: I'm already using sourcemap, but the error still show up in react-dom, i think it's the cause of babel-polyfill

Comment: See the call stack in console error and click the highest of your code. It is common to have error in react-dom if you have passed bad params to it, so you should find out what you have passed to react-dom, then place breakpoint on line.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an object as a child for a component in your render method.
Your component's child must be either a component, string or array.

Ex.

```
render() {
      return(
        <YourComponent>
          {YourComponentChild} // Check here, this must be either a string, an array or another component
        </YourComponent>
      );
    }
```

You can also follow this SO thread [Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)

Comment: First, thanks, but i can't find that i use an object as a child anywhere...