# Passing jsx element to state in router.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing a jsx element when doing a redirection via `router.push` from registration to login.

Register:

```
this.props.router.push({
  pathname: "/login",
  state: {
    intro: (<p>I'm a secret message from registration page</p>)
  }
})
```

In the Login constructor I have:

```
if (this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.intro) {
  this.state.intro = this.props.location.state.intro
}
```

It works fine for the first time. But when I refresh the Login page, I get:

`Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}).`

I have created a [code sample](https://github.com/d30jeff/redirection) to better illustrate my problem.

Comment: Please publish relevant code here, not off-site.

Comment: @jmargolisvt The two snippet above should be enough to reproduce the problem

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child  Try `console.log(typeof(this.state.intro))`  in your constructor before the `if` statement. What does that say the first time and the second time?