# show items based on the section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wanted to show a section and item relative to that section. I mean the following way

> Overdue
>
> item1
>
> item2
>
> item3
>
> No Due
>
> item1
>
> item2
>
> item3

I tried the below way, but this way, i could not generate the above ui. How do i do it?

I have the following data coming from the server
**start_time,
end_time,
reminder_time,
title,
_id**

Here is what I have tried

```
const
    ListItem = ({task}) => {
        const
            current_time = new Date();
        if (current_time > task.end_time) {
            return <View key={task._id} style={{flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1}}>
                <Text>overdue</Text>
                <Text>{task.title}</Text>
                <Text>{task.start_time}</Text>
            </View>
        }
        return (
            <View key={task._id} style={{flexDirection: 'column', flex: 1}}>
                <Text>{task.title}</Text>
                <Text>{task.start_time}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

const List = ({query}) => {
    console.log('query', query);
    if(query.loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>
    if(query.error) return <Text>Error...</Text>
    return (
        <Wrapper>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 10}}>
                    <Image
                        resizeMode="contain"
                        source={newIcon}
                        style={{width: 25, height: 25}}
                    />
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            alignSelf: 'center',
                            color: '#1F84DD'
                        }}>
                        New Task
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <FlatList
                    data={query.tasks}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem task={item} />}
                />
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

tried using `SectionList` the following way

```
<SectionList
    sections={[
        {title: 'Overdue', data:query.tasks.filter(task => task.end_time < new Date())},
        {title: 'Upcoming', data:query.tasks.filter(task => task.end_time > new Date())}
    ]}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
    renderSectionHeader={
        ({section}) => <Text>{section.title}</Text>
    }
/>
```

This way I get the error

> invariant violation: Objects not valid as a React child(found: object
>   with keys _id, start_time, end_time, remincer_time)

Comment: What is the problem that you're facing with the current code?

Comment: I get data like overdue item1, no due item1, no due item2, overdue item1, overdue item2 like this.

Comment: I could not show them in a structured way. I mean all the items that are of due date on due date section and all the items that are on no due date should be shown on no due date section not a zigzag random way

Comment: I see there is SectionList but i have no idea on how should i create the sectionData because each section should have its data. Do i filter the items based on time calculation for each section?

Comment: This is because your ListItem returns items conditionally right? As in, based on current time condition, it returns either overdue or no due together. For a structured format, you'll need to get all items that are overdue first, then get list items that have no due.

Comment: @raksheetbhat I have updated my question. I get the error when using SectionList

Comment: One reason for the error 'Objects not valid as a React child' to occur is if you're passing objects in jsx where string is expected. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child

Answer (score 0):

I see one possible solution. In your section list code, you are printing item object inside text component where it should be the title.
Replace renderItem={({item}) => {item}} with renderItem={({item}) => {item.titke}}.

Thanks.

Comment: I get time in this format(2016-08-05T08:38:50.142Z). What is the way to calculate due date and no due date with these format?

Comment: Hi, you can use moment js (https://momentjs.com/docs/) for this functionality. Convert given date to timestamp.
let x = moment("2016-08-05T08:38:50.142Z", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ").unix();
And convert current time to timestamp. let y = moment().unix();
Then if x - y > 0 Date is in the future. else if x - y < 0 Date is in the past. else Date is current date.