# Rendering a component with ternary expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I went to render a component using Ternary expression.

Currently I a doing something like this

```
 <View style={container}>
          { this.state.loaded ? 
                            (<VictoryChart
                    theme={VictoryTheme.material}
                    >
                    <VictoryArea
                        style={{ data: { fill: "#c43a31" } }}
                        data={this.coinHistoryData} 
                        x="cHT"
                        y="cHTVU"
                        domain={{ y: [0, 30000] }}
                    />
                    </VictoryChart>)
          : (<Text> Loading..</Text>)}  </View>
```

But this isn't working and Throwing an error saying `Invariant Violation`

> ExceptionsManager.js:84 Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation:
>   Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a 
>   component.

**[Question:]** How Can I fix it and render an entire component inside Ternary expression

**Ps:** According to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368342/invariant-violation-text-strings-must-be-rendered-within-a-text-component): This happens  when we do inline conditional rendering.

Comment: Did you mean this.state.loaded?

Comment: `this.setState.loaded`? do you mean `this.state.loaded`?

Comment: Fixed it! I meant `this.state.loaded`  @Zunino

Comment: `this.state.loaded` @davidhu2000

Comment: Maybe try wrapping Text component in another component (e.g View) and see if it works?

Comment: Initially `this.state.loaded` is false so It should have rendered `(<Text> Loading..</Text>)` Also, Tried what you said it didn't work @Mμ.

Comment: is this react-native? Did you import `Text`?

Comment: @davidhu2000 I did. Updated my question also it is answered now but still thanks for looking into it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen it before in `react-native`.
There are 2 reasons i know of that will throw this error:

1. returning `null` / `undefined` (not your case i think)
2. spaces after the `</Text>` tag (i think this is it in your case)

So remove the spaces in the end:

```
<View style={container}>
          { this.state.loaded ? 
                            (<VictoryChart
                    theme={VictoryTheme.material}
                    >
                    <VictoryArea
                        style={{ data: { fill: "#c43a31" } }}
                        data={this.coinHistoryData} 
                        x="cHT"
                        y="cHTVU"
                        domain={{ y: [0, 30000] }}
                    />
                    </VictoryChart>)
          : (<Text> Loading..</Text>)}  </View> //<--- spaces are here
```

So this line

```
: (<Text> Loading..</Text>)}  </View>
```

Should be like this

```
: (<Text> Loading..</Text>)}</View>
```

Comment: ...and that's why pattern `{condition && (<component>)}{!condition && (<anotherComponent>)}` look safer for React Native. No extra text put by accident :)