# How to solve Invarient violation:Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

In my React- Native project I have installed the following version of react-navigation:

**npm install react-navigation@^1.0.0-beta.11**

And then run the command:

**npm install**

After all these installation I have created a class named **WelcomeScreen.js** and here is the code given below for that-

**WelcomeScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Button
} from "react-native";

class WelcomeScreen extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        header: 'none'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Button title="Log in" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')}/>
                <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpScreen')}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
export default WelcomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

After that, I have routed this class in my **App.js** file. Here is the code given below:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen'
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppStackNavigator/>
    );
  }
}

const AppStackNavigator = new StackNavigator({
  WelcomeScreen: { screen: WelcomeScreen }
})


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Then after running my project, I am keep getting this error:

**Invarient violation:Text strings must be rendered within a  component**

[Invarient violation:Text strings must be rendered within a  component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zrc7.png)

I am not understanding why I am getting this error ? 
I have tried following solutions-

[Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368342/invariant-violation-text-strings-must-be-rendered-within-a-text-component)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20084

None of them were helpful for me. So, it would be very nice if someone help me out with this.

Comment: Any reason why are you using `react-navigation@^1.0.0-beta.11` instead of the latest `react-navigation 3`?  Might be a problem caused by this older version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used a wrong value in a header

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: "none"        
};
```

Replace `"none"` with `null`

```
static navigationOptions = {
        header: null        
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const AppStackNavigator = new StackNavigator({
  WelcomeScreen: { screen: WelcomeScreen }
})


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }**,**
});
```

is it this comma?

Comment: Yes,it was. I removed it, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider working with React's newest navigation package `react-navigation-stack` (currently in 2.0 alpha - [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator-2.0.html)).

You would implement this exactly like previous `react-navigation` stack navigators.

```js
import React from 'react'
// ...
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  { HomeScreen, AboutScreen },
  { initialRouteName: "HomeScreen" }
)

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  headerShown: false, // a more concise option, to avoid future deprecation.
}
// ... continues in next code block
```

Don't forget to wrap your application in a `react-navigation` `AppContainer` too.

```
// ...
const AppNav = createAppContainer(HomeStack)

export default AppNav
```

Of course, if you're modifying `navigationOptions` in other screens, you would simply attach the alternate options within that screen component:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        headerShow: false        
    }
    render() { 
        return (<View><Text>Welcome home.</Text></View>)
    }
}
```

As seen above, we can now use the navigation option: **headerShown: false**.

With this new package, you'll be preparing your application for the future iterations of React's navigation packages.

---

> ***Note** ;'s left out as a styling choice.*