# React Native: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to create a Profile page where the user can upload an image as the **react-native-elements Avatar** and update his profile information on a **native-base form element**.

I am also using the **React Native default ImageEditor** for image cropping and **ImagePicker from Expo** to select images.

But when I open the app on Expo, i get this error

**Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a  component**

Below is the code that I am using.

Please help.

```js
    import React from "react";
    import {
      View,
      Text,
      FlatList,
      ActivityIndicator,
      TouchableOpacity,
      StyleSheet,
     ImageEditor
    } from "react-native";
    import { Avatar } from "react-native-elements";
    import { Container, Content, Form, Input, Label, Item } from 'native-base';
    import * as Expo from 'expo';

    export default class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
     static navigationOptions = {

     }

     constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
      loading: false,
      image: null,
      error: null,
      refreshing: false
     };
    }

    async _pickImage() {
    let result = await Expo.ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    if (result.cancelled) {
      console.log('got here');
      return;
    }

    let resizedUri = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ImageEditor.cropImage(result.uri,
        {
          offset: { x: 0, y: 0 },
          size: { width: result.width, height: result.height },
          displaySize: { width: 100, height: 100 },
          resizeMode: 'contain',
        },
        (uri) => resolve(uri),
        () => reject(),
      );
    });

    // this gives you a rct-image-store URI or a base64 image tag that
    // you can use from ImageStore

    this.setState({ image: resizedUri });
    }

    render () {
    let { image } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
            <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'column', alignContent: 'flex-start', marginLeft: 20}}>
              <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', alignContent: 'flex-end'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('Save')}>
                    <Text style={{color: '#1f618d', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Save</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('Cancel')}>
                    <Text style={{color: '#1f618d', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Cancel</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={{height: 30}}></View> //Empty view
              <View style={{alignContent: 'center'}}>
                <Avatar rounded size="xlarge" title="Profile Photo" source={{ uri: this.state.image }} onPress={this._pickImage}/>
              </View>
              <View style={{height: 30}}></View> //Empty view
              <Form>
                <Item floatingLabel>
                  <Label style={styles.labelText}>First Name</Label>
                  <Input/>
                </Item>
                <Item floatingLabel>
                  <Label style={styles.labelText}>Last Name</Label>
                  <Input/>
                </Item>
                <Item floatingLabel>
                  <Label style={styles.labelText}>Email</Label>
                  <Input/>
                </Item>
              </Form>
            </View>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    )
    }
    }


    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    labelText: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: '#1f618d',
    fontWeight: '100'
    }
    });
```

Comment: `                        <View style={{height: 30}}></View> //Empty view
` cause an error

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368342/invariant-violation-text-strings-must-be-rendered-within-a-text-component

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had a semicolon which was causing this issue.

```
return (
    <View>
        <View />; // Removing this semicolon fixed it
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the way that  use comment in render //Empty View use something like that {/* Empty view */}

Answer (score 0):

Comments inside JSX must have the following syntax.

```
{/* Empty view */}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove comment using like `//Empty view` 
if you wish to add comment in render `return` method you have to use `{/*Empty View*/}` something like this.

Instead of 
`<View style={{height: 30}}></View> //Empty view` 
write 
`<View style={{height: 30}}>{/*Empty View*/}</View>`

you can not add comment directly like `//comments` in `return` function, only allow to in render or business logic parts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove the `//` comment

make use of jsx commenting style

```
{/* comment */}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you pass and empty string into a component, which is then "rendered" within a `<Text>` element.