# React native invariant violation: text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component in a form (TextField)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my code for a form in React Native which is where i seem to be getting the error. I'm confused as this renders perfectly fine in my web simulator (expo):
[working form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFIPG.png) but I get [this error when I use ios simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib4P4.png). I don't have any conditional logic or spaces/semicolons(at least what i can find) so not sure why I'm getting this error, also i'm using material ui core for my text fields in my form (which is where the error is supposedly coming from if you ref the image above). Any help would be appreciated!! pls help

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Modal } from 'react-native';
import { Formik, Form, FieldArray } from 'formik';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { recipeService } from '../services/RecipeService';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    textField: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
        marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
}));

export default function NewRecipe({ route }) {
    const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);
    const { userId } = route.params;
    const instructions = [''];
    const ingredients = [{ name: '', amount: '', optional: false }];
    const classes = useStyles();
    const input = useRef();
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
             <Formik
                initialValues={{ userId: userId, name: "", summary: "", instructions: instructions, ingredients: ingredients }}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                    recipeService.createRecipe(values).then(
                        (response) => {
                            console.log(response);
                            setShowAlert(true);
                            console.log("alert = " + showAlert);
                            actions.resetForm({});
                            return (
                                <Modal
                                    animationType="slide"
                                    transparent={false}
                                    visible={true}
                                    onRequestClose={
                                        () => { setShowAlert(false); }
                                    }>
                                    <View style={styles.modalView}>
                                        <Text>Recipe saved!</Text>
                                        <Button
                                            margin="normal"
                                            type="button"
                                            variant="contained"
                                            color="default"
                                            className={classes.textField}
                                            onClick={() => actions.resetForm({})}
                                        >
                                            New Recipe
                                    </Button>
                                    </View>
                                </Modal>
                            )
                        }
                    )
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                }
                }
            >{({ values, handleChange, handleBlur }) => (
                    <Form>
                        <TextField
                            fullWidth
                            variant="outlined"
                            id="name"
                            name="name"
                            label="Name"
                            value={values.name}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            fullWidth
                            multiline
                            variant="outlined"
                            id="summary"
                            name="summary"
                            label="Summary"
                            className={classes.textField}
                            value={values.summary}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <FieldArray
                                name="ingredients"
                                render={arrayHelpers => (
                                    <div>
                                        {values.ingredients.map((item, index) => (
                                            <div key={index}>
                                                <TextField
                                                    variant="outlined"
                                                    label="Ingredient Name"
                                                    name={`ingredients.${index}.name`}
                                                    value={item.name}
                                                    margin="normal"
                                                    className={classes.textField}
                                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                                    style={{ margin: 8, width: 233 }}
                                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                />
                                                <TextField
                                                    variant="outlined"
                                                    label="Amount"
                                                    name={`ingredients.${index}.amount`}
                                                    value={item.amount}
                                                    margin="normal"
                                                    className={classes.textField}
                                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                                    style={{ margin: 8, width: 100 }}
                                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                                />
                                                <Button
                                                    margin="normal"
                                                    type="button"
                                                    color="secondary"
                                                    variant="outlined"
                                                    margin="dense"
                                                    style={{ margin: 8, width: 30 }}
                                                    className={classes.textField}
                                                    onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                                                > x
                                            </Button>
                                                <Button
                                                    margin="normal"
                                                    type="button"
                                                    variant="contained"
                                                    color="default"
                                                    className={classes.textField}
                                                    onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({ name: '', amount: '', optional: false })}
                                                >Add
                                              </Button>
                                            </div>
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <FieldArray
                            name="instructions"
                            render={arrayHelpers => (
                                <div>
                                    {values.instructions.map((item, index) => (
                                        <div key={index}>
                                            <TextField
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                label="Instruction"
                                                name={`instructions.${index}`}
                                                value={item}
                                                margin="normal"
                                                className={classes.textField}
                                                onChange={handleChange}
                                                style={{ margin: 8, width: 350 }}
                                                onBlur={handleBlur}
                                            />
                                            <Button
                                                margin="normal"
                                                type="button"
                                                color="secondary"
                                                variant="outlined"
                                                margin="dense"
                                                style={{ margin: 8, width: 30 }}
                                                className={classes.textField}
                                                onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                                            > x
                                            </Button>
                                        </div>
                                    ))}
                                    <Button
                                        margin="normal"
                                        type="button"
                                        variant="contained"
                                        color="default"
                                        className={classes.textField}
                                        onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push('')}
                                    >Add
                                    </Button>
                                </div>
                            )}
                        />
                        <div>
                            <Button color="primary" variant="contained" className={classes.textField} fullWidth type="submit">
                                Submit
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368342/invariant-violation-text-strings-must-be-rendered-within-a-text-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `@material-ui/core` for React Native projects.

`@material-ui/core` can work for expo because it's web based. But I'm pretty sure that it won't work for native environments.

I'd like to recommend alternatives, but I don't use material design for React Native because it simply doesn't fit to iOS.