# Implemented supermarket order strikethrough system in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Implemented the supermarket order strikethrough system in React Native, it gives me the following error "text strings must be redered within a  component", what the code does is have a button inside the flatlist and it strikes when I press that button for that what I did was an arrow function which changed the status from 0 to 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81fqt.jpg)

I share code.

```
import { FlatList, Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

import Buttons from './components/buttons';
import Menu from './components/menu';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import TT from './components/textBox';

export default function App() {

  //useState

  const [product, setProduct] = useState('');
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
  const [measure, setMeasure] = useState('Seleccione una ...');
  const [order, setorder] = useState([]);

  //funciones

  const onChangeProduct = (text) => { setProduct(text) };
  const onChangeQuantity = (text) => { setQuantity(text) };
  const onPressButton = () => {
    if (product != '' && quantity != 0 && measure != 'Seleccione una ...') {
      setorder([...order, { id: Date.now(),  product: product, quantity: quantity, measure: measure, status: 0 }]);
      setProduct('');
      setQuantity(0);
      setMeasure('Seleccione una ...');
    }
    else
    {
      setProduct('');
      setQuantity(0);
      setMeasure('Seleccione una ...');
    }
  };

  const renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      if (item.status == 0) {
      <>
        <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.product + ' - ' + item.quantity + ' - ' + item.measure}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemButton} onPress={tachado(item.id)}>
          <Text>X</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>  
      </>
      }else{
        <Text style={styles.itemTextTachado}>{item.product + ' - ' + item.quantity + ' - ' + item.measure}</Text>
      }  
    </View>
  )

  const tachado = (id) => {
    setorder(order.map((item) => { 
      if (item.id == id) {
        item.status = 1;
      }
      return item;
    }))
  }
  //useRef

  const pickerRef = useRef();

  function open() {
    pickerRef.current.focus();
  }

  function close() {
    pickerRef.current.blur();
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
      <Menu />
      
      <View style={styles.textNomList}>     
        <Text style={styles.textNom}>Lista del 06/09/2022 Supermercado</Text> 
      </View>
      
      <View style={styles.textContainerTitle}>
        <Text style={styles.textTitle}>Lista de Supermercado </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.TextInputContainer}>
        <TT placeholder="Producto" value={product} onChangeText={onChangeProduct}/>
        <TT placeholder="Cantidad" value={quantity} onChangeText={onChangeQuantity}/>
         <Text style={styles.textPicker}> Medidas - {measure}</Text>
        <Picker  style={styles.picker}
         selectedValue = { measure } 
         onValueChange = { (itemValue, itemIndex) =>
          setMeasure(itemValue) }>
          <Picker.Item  label = "Unidad" value = "Unidad" />
          <Picker.Item  label = "Kgr" value = "Kg" />
        </Picker>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Buttons title="Agregar" bkcolor="#6E04BF" color="#ffffff" onPress={onPressButton} />
      </View>
      
    <FlatList 
      data={order}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor = {(item )=> item.id.toString()}

    />
    
      <StatusBar style="auto" />

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#6E04BF',
    color: '#fff',     
  }, 

  textNomList: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    alignItems: 'baseline',
  },

  textNom: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',    
  },

  textContainerTitle: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  textTitle: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },

  TextInputContainer: {
    marginTop: 40,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },

  TextInput: {
    height: 33,
    color: '#6E04BF',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    fontSize: 15,
    selectionColor: '#fff',
    placeholderTextColor: '#6E04BF',
    marginBottom: 15,
  },

  textPicker: {
  color:'#fff',
  },  
  
  itemPicker: {
    color: '#fff',
  },
  
  picker: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',          
  },

  buttonContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
    height: 33,
  },

  itemContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 10,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    color: '#6E04BF',
    fontSize: 15,
    borderRadius: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },

  itemText: {
    textDecorationLine:'none',
  },

  itemTextTachado: {
    textDecorationLine:'line-through',
  },
});
```

what am I doing wrong

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368342/invariant-violation-text-strings-must-be-rendered-within-a-text-component)

Comment: The issue is in your renderItem callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution I found was this

First, change the idea of converting it from 0 and 1 to a boolean system, that is, true or false in the status key of the object that the state order points to.

then to define that if the product is crossed out or selected from the list, I did that with a ternary inside the style braces inside the text in the TEXT label of the rederItem function.

And for everything to work well, I simply use the arrow function in the TouchableOpacity in the onPree event, I share the code.

```
import { FlatList, Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

import Buttons from './components/buttons';
import Menu from './components/menu';
import Pickers from './components/Pickers';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import TT from './components/textBox';

export default function App() {

  //useState

  const [product, setProduct] = useState('');
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
  const [measure, setMeasure] = useState('Seleccione una ...');
  const [order, setorder] = useState([]);

  //funciones

  const onChangeProduct = (text) => { setProduct(text) };
  const onChangeQuantity = (text) => { setQuantity(text) };
  const onPressButton = () => {
    if (product != '' && quantity != 0 && measure != 'Seleccione una ...') {
      setorder([...order, { id: Date.now().toString(),  product: product, quantity: quantity, measure: measure, status: false }]);
      setProduct('');
      setQuantity(0);
      setMeasure('Seleccione una ...');
    }
  };

  const renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <Text style={ item.status == false ? styles.itemText : styles.itemTextTachado}>{item.product + ' - ' + item.quantity + ' - ' + item.measure}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addStatus(item.id)}>
       <Text style = { styles.itemTextButton}>X</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
  
  const addStatus = (id) => {
    const newOrder = order.map((item) => {
      if (item.id == id) {
        item.status = !item.status;
      }
      return item;
    });
    setorder(newOrder);
  };


  //useRef

  const pickerRef = useRef();

  function open() {
    pickerRef.current.focus();
  }

  function close() {
    pickerRef.current.blur();
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
      <Menu />
      
      <View style={styles.textNomList}>     
        <Text style={styles.textNom}> Supermercado </Text> 
      </View>
      
      <View style={styles.textContainerTitle}>
        <Text style={styles.textTitle}>Lista de Supermercado </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.TextInputContainer}>
        <TT placeholder="Producto" value={product} onChangeText={onChangeProduct}/>
        <TT placeholder="Cantidad" value={quantity} onChangeText={onChangeQuantity}/>
         <Text style={styles.textPicker}> Medidas - {measure}</Text>
        <Pickers stateFirst={measure} stateSecond={setMeasure}></Pickers>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Buttons title="Agregar" bkcolor="#6E04BF" color="#ffffff" onPress={onPressButton} />
      </View>
      
    <FlatList 
      data={order}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor = {(item )=> item.id.toString()}

    />
    
      <StatusBar style="auto" />

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#6E04BF',
    color: '#fff',     
  }, 

  textNomList: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    alignItems: 'baseline',
  },

  textNom: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',    
  },

  textContainerTitle: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  textTitle: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },

  textPicker: {
    color:'#fff',
    },  

  TextInputContainer: {
    marginTop: 40,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },

  TextInput: {
    height: 33,
    color: '#6E04BF',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    fontSize: 15,
    selectionColor: '#fff',
    placeholderTextColor: '#6E04BF',
    marginBottom: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },

 

  buttonContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
    height: 33,
  },

  itemContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 15,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    color: '#6E04BF',
    fontSize: 15,
    borderRadius: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },

  itemText: {
    textDecorationLine:'none',
  },

  itemTextTachado: {
    textDecorationLine:'line-through',
  },

  itemTextButton: {
    color: '#6E04BF',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },

});
```

Thank you