# Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component in BottomTabBar (at SceneView.tsx:132)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I have Implemented a bottomTab Navigation in my App. I got this error

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

This error is located at:
    in BottomTabBar (at SceneView.tsx:132)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:125)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:124)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:217)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:281)
```

I have tried to solve this issue but i unable to solve this issue. because i unable to understand that , This error is related to code OR node modules. Please suggest the solution.

```
const BottomTabBar = (tabProps) => (
    <>
      {bottomTabData.tabs && bottomTabData.tabs.length && (
        <BottomTab.Navigator
          tabBarOptions={{
            safeAreaInset: { bottom: 'never', top: 'never' },
          }}
          lazy
          // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
          tabBar={(props) => <BottomTabComp {...props} tabsData={bottomTabData} />}
          initialRouteName={bottomTabData && bottomTabData.tabs && bottomTabData.tabs[(notifyData && notifyData.bottom_tab_index) || bottomTabData.highlighted_tab_index].title}
          // initialRouteName={bottomTabData && bottomTabData.tabs && bottomTabData.tabs[2].title}
        >
          {bottomTabData.tabs && bottomTabData.tabs.length && bottomTabData.tabs.map((tab) => (
            <BottomTab.Screen
              key={tab.id}
              name={tab.title}
              initialParams={{
                data: tabProps.route && tabProps.route.params && tabProps.route.params.data,
                notifyData,
              }}
              component={tab && tab.page_type === 'DISCOVER' ? DiscoverStack : tab.page_type === 'NOTIFICATION' ? NotificationTabStack : HomeStack}
            />
          ))}
        </BottomTab.Navigator>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: upload BottomTanBar

Comment: Yes, we need to see the implementation of your `SceneView.tsx` where you actually use the `BottomTabBar`. But providing only the error logs is not sufficient.

Comment: this kind issues usually because you have typo in your code! check if you accidentally add comma or some text at the end of your brackets ! or you just add comment on your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368342/invariant-violation-text-strings-must-be-rendered-within-a-text-component)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code there is a  `{''}` outside of `<Text>Some Text</Text>`

Probably look like this -> `<Text>Some Text</Text>{''}`

Please check if this is the case