# React Native error, "Text strings must be rendered with <Text> component" but its not a text string?

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am trying to make a chat app in react native, with firebase for data and authentication.
I am now trying to make the screen which will display a chat feed, fetching a collection of messages from my firebase project using firestore.
During my try to make such a screen, a error occured;
"Text strings must be rendered with <Text> component", along with indicator showing this was the error, on setLoading(false)

```
useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = firestore()
        .collection('chats')
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
        .limitToLast(15)
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
          const chatsArr = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const id = doc.id;
            const data = doc.data();
            chatsArr.push({id, ...data});
          });
          setLoading(false);
          setChats(chatsArr);
        });
  
      return () => {
        unsubscribe();
        setLoading(false);
      };
    }, []);
```

Here is the stack:

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by MainScreen)
    in MainScreen (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen
    in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in Chattr(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

And here is all the code of the MainScreen:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Alert,
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import ChatMessage from '../components/ChatMessage';
import SignOutButton from '../components/SignOutButton';

const MainScreen = () => {                    // Input text
    const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);                    // Chat messages
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);       
    
    const handleSignOut = async () => await auth().signOut();// Loading state
  
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = firestore()
        .collection('chats')
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
        .limitToLast(15)
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
          const chatsArr = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const id = doc.id;
            const data = doc.data();
            chatsArr.push({id, ...data});
          });
          setLoading(false);
          setChats(chatsArr);
        });
  
      return () => {
        unsubscribe();
        setLoading(false);
      };
    }, []);
  
    if (loading) {
      return <ActivityIndicator />;  // Show loader while loading chats
    } else {
      const username = auth().currentUser.displayName;
  
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          // Top app bar
          <View style={styles.textContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{username}</Text>
            <SignOutButton handleClick={handleSignOut} />
          </View>
  
          // Chats container
          <View style={styles.chatStyle}>
            {chats && (
              <FlatList
                data={chats}
                renderItem={({item}) => <ChatMessage key={item.id} chat={item} />}
              />
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    chatStyle: {
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      height: '90%',
      margin: 0,
      padding: 0,
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',
      // overflowY: 'scroll',
    },
    container: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      margin: 0,
      marginTop: 0,
      marginBottom: 0,
      padding: 0,
      paddingBottom: '15%',
      paddingTop: 0,
      backgroundColor: '#151718',
      alignItems: 'flex-start',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    inputContainer: {
      width: '100%',
      height: 60,
      position: 'absolute',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      margin: 0,
      padding: 0,
      paddingBottom: 0,
      backgroundColor: '#151718',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#1e2123',
      borderLeftWidth: 0,
      borderRightWidth: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
    },
    text: {
      fontWeight: '600',
      fontSize: 20,
      color: '#030303',
      marginRight: 'auto',
      marginLeft: 8,
      padding: 4,
    },
    textContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      height: 60,
      width: '100%',
      margin: 0,
      padding: 8,
      elevation: 6,
      backgroundColor: '#ffa600',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
  });

export default MainScreen;
```

My question is, why am i getting this error? I have really no clue at the moment where this is occuring and i have sat for some hours now struggling to find a solution.

Ran npm start, npm start android, app builded succesfully and error occured, with no screen rendered behind the error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368342/text-strings-must-be-rendered-within-a-text-component)

Comment: I have looked at it and i don't seem to being able to find an answer i am looking for. But thanks anyways for directing me to it

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following from your code

```js
// Top app bar

// Chats container
```

This is not viewed as a comment but as text in the return statement so either remove it or change it to the following

```js
{/* Top app bar */}

{/* Chats container */}
```

Comment: Tried it out, no change, still getting the same error.

Comment: I have edited my answer, have you tried it with both items?

Comment: yes, i have tried to delete all comments but the issue still persists. Funny enough, i get no error when i delete setLoading(false), but then i will just keep loading forever and not show any results.

Comment: Thats correct because the `ActivityIndicator` does not contain any text. I would suggest installing `esLint` since it detects and marks errors as this for example.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're seeing, "Text strings must be rendered within a  component," typically means that you are attempting to render a plain string outside of a  component at some point in your component. React Native need this in order to render text.

The following line of code in your MainScreen component may be the source of the problem:

```
<View style={styles.textContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.text}>{username || 'Guest'}</Text>
  <SignOutButton handleClick={handleSignOut} />
</View>
```

Make sure the string username is valid. To avoid the problem, you may need to handle the condition where the username is null or undefined. The  component can be conditionally rendered or you can use a default value.

This guarantees that the default username will be 'Guest' in the event that it is false (null or undefined). Adapt this to the logic of your application.

If the problem still occurs, you might also want to make sure that you are not attempting to render a bare string without first enclosing it in a  component by looking at the ChatMessage component.

Furthermore, confirm that no additional code segments render plain strings in the absence of a  component. The setLoading(false) line is the source of the error message; however, other components' rendering may be the cause of the problem.