React native issue : Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> Component
in my react native app I get the followinf error: texts strings must be rendered withn a text tag, the error is on this line:
{ root.userStore.work && root.userStore.work != '' && (
                <Text allowFontScaling={false} style={{ paddingTop:10,paddingHorizontal:0, color:'rgb(125,125,125)', position:'relative',fontSize:14,fontFamily:'IBMPlexSans-Regular' ,marginBottom:0,alignSelf:'flex-start' }}>{ t('currentCharacters', { characters : calculateWorkRemainingCharacters(root.userStore.work.length)} ) }</Text>

calculateWorkRemainingCharacters function looks like this:
const calculateWorkRemainingCharacters = (currentLength ) => {
        let maxLength = 20;
        return maxLength - currentLength;
    }


Does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368342/text-strings-must-be-rendered-within-a-text-component ?

The problem in your code lies here
{ root.userStore.work && root.userStore.work != '' && (
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ here
  ....

Your root.userStore.work does not necessarily resolve to a boolean result. Hence, it will be returned in the react component tree and react-native will try to render it. But these data types aren't allowed to be displayed outside a Text component.
Solution 1:
{ !!root.userStore.work && root.userStore.work != '' && (
//^^ changed here
<Text allowFontScaling={false} style={{ paddingTop:10,paddingHorizontal:0, color:'rgb(125,125,125)', position:'relative',fontSize:14,fontFamily:'IBMPlexSans-Regular' ,marginBottom:0,alignSelf:'flex-start' }}>{ t('currentCharacters', { characters : calculateWorkRemainingCharacters(root.userStore.work.length)} ) }</Text>}

Solution 2:
{ root.userStore.work && root.userStore.work != '' ? (
//                                                 ^ made it ternary
                <Text allowFontScaling={false} style={{ paddingTop:10,paddingHorizontal:0, color:'rgb(125,125,125)', position:'relative',fontSize:14,fontFamily:'IBMPlexSans-Regular' ,marginBottom:0,alignSelf:'flex-start' }}>{ t('currentCharacters', { characters : calculateWorkRemainingCharacters(root.userStore.work.length)} ) }</Text> : null}

