# How do i properly initialize my state, and then render that data onto the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm setting up a "My account" page, I need to display the payload created after the componentDidMount() function. However, When I set my state and render it,only my email renders. How do I access the rest of the payload

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
//import...


//const StyledCard 

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
`;

class MyAccount extends Component {

  state = {
    data: ['default',],

    };


  async componentDidMount() {
    const payload = { email: "tynantynan8@gmail.com",
       name: "Tynan McGrady",
       surname: "",
      middleName:  "",
      number: "(805) 240-6258",
      adress: "407 s. mayfair ave",};


   //var payload = ["tynantynan8@gmail.com", "Tynan McGrady", " ", " ","(805) 240-6258","407 s. mayfair ave"];
    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:1234/user/profile", payload)
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        console.log(data);


        this.setState({
          data:data
        })


      });




}
  render() {

    return (
      <container>
        <row>
          <StyledDiv>
            <StyledCard>
              <Card.Header as="h5">Profile</Card.Header>          
              <Card.Body>


                <Container>
                <Row>

                  <p> {this.state.data.email} </p>
        <p> {this.state.data.name} </p>
                </Row>
                </Container>
              </Card.Body>
            </StyledCard>

          </StyledDiv>
        </row>
      </container>
    );
  }
}

export default MyAccount;
```

Expected results, display items on the page using this.state.data or something similar

These are the errors I get:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id,
>   first_name, middle_name, last_name, dob, email, address, __v}). If you
>   meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428879/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-if-you-meant-to-render-a-collection-of-c)

Comment: Do not try to render your data directly like this. As you can see, you can't render an object. Use its properties separately, like first_name, middle_name, etc.  If it is an array you should map over it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `this.state.data` is an object, you would need to access the keys inside the object in order to display them.

For example...

```
{ this.state.data.first_name }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot render object
Things that can be rendered are 
* Strings
* Components 
* Array of Components 
* DOM object
The data from the response is and object.
Get the required information from the object and then display it 
Eg:  { this.state.data.value }

Comment: how do i get the required information from the object and then display it. My code is above