# 'Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {results, info})'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use fetch in React I got this error:

> 'Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with
> keys {results, info})'

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      IsLoding: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
        data: data,
        IsLoding: true
      }));[enter image description here][1]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          Hello
          {this.state.data}
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

the error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/klKKP.jpg

When I try `console.log(data)` it's working but when I try to get the data to page not working.

Comment: what is the `data` that your API returns, and that you see in the console. (We can't see your console output.) Your `render` will only work if it's a simple string (or array of those), but it seems from the error that it's an object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428879/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-if-you-meant-to-render-a-collection-of-c)

Comment: this is the API https://api.randomuser.me its should return names and gender , and nothing in the console

Comment: @Ahmed, check the question above. You can't render a whole object, you should use the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the data, because you can't render an object.

For example if you wanna see only the genders try this:

```
{this.state.data.results.map(item => <p>{item.gender}</p>)}
```

Or you could implement a user component that render the user information

```
{this.state.data.results.map(item => <User item={item}} />)}
```

Dont forget to add the key prop when mapping an array!

https://es.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.data` gets populated with an object `{results, info}`, from there you can render only the properties that are strings or numbers, some examples

For arrays `[]`, you will need to map them

```
{this.state.data.results.map(result => result.gender)}
```

in this case, results is an array of objects, `map` will get one by one and store it in the variable **result**, and this will be an object

For objects `{}`, you will need to find the property you want to render

```
{this.state.data.info.results}
```

Now if what you want is to render the whole object as it is, you need to convert it to a string like this

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 4)}</pre>
```