# React cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I get the `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, description, status, priority, created, deadline, emp}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` error and followed [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428879/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-if-you-meant-to-render-a-collection-of-c) to solve the issue.

Upon running the object with the `map` function I get the null error. Upon passing the object `JSON.stringify()` I get the string ensuring data is returned by the API.

This is my data.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "asfd",
        "status": "ass",
        "priority": "p",
        "created": "2022-08-21",
        "deadline": "2022-07-28",
        "emp": 1
    }
]
```

This is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const TaskPage = ({match}) => {
    let taskId = match.params.id
    let [task, setTask] = useState(null)

      useEffect(() => {
        getTask()
    }, [taskId])

    let getTask = async () => {
        if (taskId === 'new') return

        let response = await fetch(`/task/task/${taskId}/`)
        let data = await response.json()
        setTask(data)
    }

  return (

    <div>

      {task.map(task => <div>{task.id}</div>)}
      <div>{JSON.stringify(task)}</div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `useState(null)`. You can't `map` over `null`.

Comment: Just change null from there pass empty array.   `const [task, setTask] = useState([])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const TaskPage = ({match}) => {
    let taskId = match.params.id
    let [task, setTask] = useState([])

      useEffect(() => {
        getTask()
    }, [taskId])

    let getTask = async () => {
        if (taskId === 'new') return

        let response = await fetch(`/task/task/${taskId}/`)
        let data = await response.json()
        setTask(data)
    }

  return (

    <div>

      {task.length && task.map(task => <div>{task.id}</div>)}
      <div>{JSON.stringify(task)}</div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching data which is an `async` operation. Before the data is loaded, the state is `null`. As the state is null, you can't map to a null element. Either you set the state to empty array like this.

```
let [task, setTask] = useState(null)
```

Or you can do this in return.

```
<div>

  {task && task.map(task => <div>{task.id}</div>)}
  <div>{JSON.stringify(task)}</div>
</div>
```

This will check if the task has some data and then it will use the map function.