# where is problem in code axios.get "response.data"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

**Set data:**

> `export const setIngredients = (ingredients) => {return { type: actionTypes.SET_INGREDIENTS,ingredients : ingredients}}`

**Get data:**

> `export const initIngredients = () => {return  dispatch => {axios.get('....').then(response => {dispatch(setIngredients(response.data));}).catch( error => {dispatch(fetchIngredientsFailed())})} }`

**Error:**

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {objectId, name, createdAt, updatedAt, value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

return dispatch => {
axios.get('......').then(response => {**`dispatch(setIngredients(response.data)`**);}).catch( error => {dispatch(fetchIngredientsFailed())}

Comment: Try to check if your response.data has data. Try using the if-else condition on that matter. It may return an undefined value.

Comment: Please add the rest of your component code as a [mcve]. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be the issue with your API fetching Axios code, Instead its the issue in rendering logic.

Somewhere in your JSX code, You are directly referencing an object/array of `ingredients` that's why it is giving this error. As react don't support object or array as a child component.

You can also refer this question, [Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428879/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-if-you-meant-to-render-a-collection-of-c?rq=2)