# Invariant Violation-Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, title, category, stock, price}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in li (created by ListGroupItem)
    in ListGroupItem (at App.js:36)
    in ul (created by ListGroup)
    in ListGroup (at App.js:35)
    in div (at App.js:34)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)
```

what does this error mean? How can I solve this problem
My render component is here:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ListGroup>
          <ListGroupItem>{this.state.movies}</ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>Dapibus ac facilisis in</ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>Morbi leo risus</ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>Porta ac consectetur ac</ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>Vestibulum at eros</ListGroupItem>
        </ListGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child) might help.

Comment: i think this.state.movies is a object and react expects a string

Answer (score 0):

**JSX doesn't supports objects.** It supports arrays or strings.

So use Object.keys or Object.entries to return an array of keys and values.

Map through the array to render the elements in the UI

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ListGroup>
          <ListGroupItem>
          {
          Object.entries(this.state.movies).map(([key, value]) => (
           <>
           {key}
           {value}
           </> 
            ));
            }

          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>Dapibus ac facilisis in</ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>Morbi leo risus</ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>Porta ac consectetur ac</ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>Vestibulum at eros</ListGroupItem>
        </ListGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListGroupItem>{this.state.movies}</ListGroupItem>
```

The error is because of this line. Could you be more specific in what you are trying to achieve? If you want to directly print the object, use

```
<ListGroupItem>{JSON.stringify(this.state.movies)}</ListGroupItem>
```