# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {information})

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Learning React and stuck at this error

**Invariant Violation
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {information}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

What am I doing wrong, confused in the Array error part
Below are my main files

**Myinfo.js file**

```js
import React from "react"
import Myinfoo from './Myinfoo'
import info from './info.js'

// function Myinfo() {
// const infomation = info.map(it => <Myinfoo key={it.id} name= {<h1>{it.name}</h1>} price ={it.price} description = {it.description}/>)
//     return (
//         <div className="todo">
//             {infomation}
//         </div>
//     )
// }
class Myinfo extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            infos: info
        }   
    }
    render(){
        //console.log(this.state.infos)
        const infod = [];
        const information = this.state.infos.map(it => <Myinfoo key={it.id} infos1={it} />)
        //const information = this.state.infos
        //console.log(information)
        return(
            {information}
        )
    }
}
export default Myinfo
```

**Myinfoo .js file**

```js
import React from "react"

// function Myinfoo(props) {
    

// }
class Myinfoo extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="item">
                <input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.description} />

                <p style={{ display: this.props.name ? "block" : "none" }}>{this.props.name}</p>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Myinfoo
```

Here is my Json Data
**info.js**

```js
const info = [
    {
        id:"1",
        name:"Pencil",
        
        description : true
    },
    {
        id: "12",
        name: "Pencil1",
        
        description: false
    },
    {
        id: "1223",
        name: "Eraser",
        
        description: false
    },
    {
        id: "134",
        name: "Eraser1",
        
        description: true
    }


]



export default info
```

Comment: `return( {information} )` does indeed return an object, do `return information` or `return <>{information}</>` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a root tag. Try this:

```
return
(
    <div>
        {information}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: This worked, but I am confused, can I know the reason for the <div> tag (Sorry I am confused here little bit)

Comment: @FaiyazSundrani The div is what makes it a JSX body (where `{information}` is a wrapped expression). Without it, it's just a regular Javascript expression, where `{information}` is a plain JS object.

Comment: Everything must be inside a root tag. So if you have for example "return (<p></p><p></p>)", like you have in a list,  react will throw an error. It doesn't need to be a div, but it must be something wrapping the whole thing.

Comment: Simply `return information`would work as well. An array of proper elements is handled by React..