# axios is not implementing post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, post, http-post

i am trying to post data with axios (NodeJS, ReactJS) but i ended up getting this errors
[image]

[image]

and here is my posting code

```
axios({
              method: 'post',
              url: '/api/signup',
              data: 
              {
               username: this.state.username,
               name: this.state.name,
               surname: this.state.surname,
               email: this.state.email,
               password: this.state.password,
               confirm_password: this.state.confirm_password,
              }
       })
       .then(res => res.data)
       .then(url => window.location.href = url.location)
       .catch(error => this.setState({errorBol: true, errorMessage: error}))
```

and my nodeJS code

```
router.post('/', async (req,res)=>{
   const username = req.body.username;
   const name = req.body.name;
   const surname = req.body.surname;
   const email = req.body.email;
   const password = req.body.password;
   const confirm_password = req.body.confirm_password;

    console.log(username)
    console.log(name)
    console.log(surname)
    console.log(email)
    console.log(password)
    console.log(confirm_password)

   res.status(200).send({location: '/'})
})
```

i have config for /api/signup like this

```
 router.use('/api/main', require('./sinupfilename'))
```

so problem is not in router.post('/')

about problem:

i am implementing post request form submission and have a validation for form and it works perfectly but it gives me an errors above when i click submit button so if anyone know clue, i will be glad to hear it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `issue is not with axios but with your render function`. The above issue comes when you are trying to render any object instead of a valid react element.
The issue might be at setState for errorMessage variable. Try printing the errorMessage or typeof errorMessage for further info. It should not be an object.

The error is an `javascript object` if you read the [official documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) for axios.

You need to extract the error message and set it in your errorMessage variable. It should work fine. As per the docs, the same can be done is this similar manner:

```
const err = ""
if (error.response) {
  err = error.response.data
} else if (error.request) {
  err = error.request.response
} else {
  err = error.message
}
this.setState({errorBol: true, errorMessage: err})
```

Basically, any thing which needs to be rendered has to be valid react element like string, html tags, numbers but not object. So, you need to make sure that whatever is rendered, it needs to be a valid react element. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)

Hope it helps, revert for any doubts.

Comment: i changed ` .catch(error => this.setState({errorBol: true, errorMessage: error}))` to
 .catch(error => alert(error))  and got this alert
  Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have a look. If it doesn't solve the issue, please update the question with the code of your React component.

Comment: before i do that.as my nodeJs server running on 5000 port and my  react 3000 i tried this
`      axios({
                  url: 'localhost:5000/api/signup',
              })
              .then(res => res.data)
              .then(url => console.log(url))
              .catch(error => alert(error)) `
and it alerted Network error with this message in console: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:5000/api/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: do i need "cors" module?

Comment: thank you actually it worked , i also had problems with other stuff but when displaying error showed up your  solution worked as well.