# Could not get animation to work with AMP and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amp-html

I am working on a React AMP project where I need to do some tweaky animation with AMP to show and hide a button when the window is scrolled.

As AMP Animation tag expects an object in the children on `<amp-animation>` but `React` does not allows object as it's children.

Here is the code I am trying with:

```
import React from 'react';
const showAnim = {
  "duration": "200ms",
  "fill": "both",
  "iterations": "1",
  "direction": "alternate",
  "animations": [
    {
      "selector": "#download-button",
      "keyframes": [
        { "opacity": "1", "visibility": "visible" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
const hideAnim = {
  "duration": "200ms",
  "fill": "both",
  "iterations": "1",
  "direction": "alternate",
  "animations": [
    {
      "selector": "#download-button",
      "keyframes": [
        { "opacity": "0", "visibility": "hidden" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
export default class Animate extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
  }

  onScroll = () => {
    console.log('scrolling')
  }

  renderShowAnimation = () => <amp-animation id="showAnim" layout="nodisplay" src="">
    <script type="application/json">
      {showAnim}
    </script>
  </amp-animation >;

  renderHideAnimation = () => <amp-animation id="showAnim" layout="nodisplay">
    <script type="application/json">
    {hideAnim}
    </script>
  </amp-animation >;


  render() {
    return (
      <main onScroll={this.onScroll} >
        <div>
         {this.renderShowAnimation()}
          {this.renderHideAnimation()}
              <div className="download-button" id="download-button" role="button">
                Download
                <amp-position-observer
                  on="enter:hideAnim.start; exit:showAnim.start"
                  layout="nodisplay">
                </amp-position-observer>
              </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    )
  }
}
```

Now when I am trying to run the app I am getting the following error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {duration, fill, iterations, direction, animations}).
```

I tried to put an `onScroll` event also but it is also not working in AMP.
If someone has an aleternative or if something is wrong in my code please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)?

Comment: is there an answer for this, im also having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

`amp-animation` expects a JSON as a child, not a Javascript object. (They are similar in syntax, but different.) Even though you wrote the object in JSON syntax, `showAnim` and `hideAnim` end up interpreted as objects by javascript. You can convert them to JSON with `JSON.stringify()`.

Simplifying your issue for a second, if you look at one of their [examples](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-animation/?format=websites).

```
<amp-animation layout="nodisplay">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "selector": "#target-id",
      "duration": "1s",
      "keyframes": {"opacity": 1}
    }
  </script>
</amp-animation>
```

The problem is if you paste this into the render method of React, you'll get errors because the `{` escapes the jsx and it now expects javascript. One way to fix this is to use React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
<amp-animation layout="nodisplay">
  <script type="application/json" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 
    JSON.stringify(
      {
        "selector": "#target-id",
        "duration": "1s",
        "keyframes": {"opacity": 1}
      }
    )
  }}>
  </script>
</amp-animation>
```

In your case, you can change your two functions to

```
renderShowAnimation = () => <amp-animation id="showAnim" layout="nodisplay" src="">
    <script type="application/json" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: JSON.stringify(showAnim)}}>
    </script>
  </amp-animation >;

  renderHideAnimation = () => <amp-animation id="showAnim" layout="nodisplay">
    <script type="application/json" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: JSON.stringify(showAnim)}}>
    </script>
  </amp-animation >
```

Answer (score -1):

AMP not allow define custom javascript (unlimited js) and custom event listener except `on` attribute). You can implement some dynamic functionality in AMP with amp-bind component and amp-script component

Comment: You can add custom javascript, under heavy restrictions, with the new <amp-script> tag: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript/?format=websites