# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to achieve a simple functionality, `onPress` of a button it should add `placeName` to place array and show it in the view but I seem to get an error, Please help

this my code,

```
export default class App extends Component{

  state = {
    placeName: "",
    places: []
  }

  onChangeName = (val) => {
    this.setState({
      placeName: val
    })
  }

  placeSubmitHandler = () => {
    if(this.state.placeName === "") {
      alert('enter something');
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          places: prevState.places.concat(prevState.placeName)
        }
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const placesOutput = this.state.places.map((place, i) => (
        <Text key={i}>{place}</Text>
    ));
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput 
            style={{width: 300}}
            value={this.state.textInput}
            placeholder='enter anything'
            onChange={this.onChangeName}
            style={styles.placeInput}
            />
            <Button title='Add' style={styles.placeButton} onPress={this.placeSubmitHandler}/>
        </View>
        <View>
          {placesOutput}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

this is error im getting,

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {dispatchConfig, _targetInst, _dispatchListeners, _dispatchInstances, type, target, currentTarget, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelable, timeStamp, defaultPrevented, isTrusted, nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in RCTText (at Text.js:154)
    in TouchableText (at Text.js:278)
    in Text (at App.js:48)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at App.js:62)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at App.js:51)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

I'm new to react native, so I have no idea about this.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child It might help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `<TextInput>`you are using an `onChange` prop instead of `onChangeText`, so that you're tryng to render an object in a `<Text>`. Simply change that prop and it should work

```
  <TextInput
    style={styles.placeInput}
    value={this.state.textInput}
    placeholder="enter anything"
    onChangeText={this.onChangeName}
  />
```

Also note that you're duplicating its `style` property. Unify them or pass them as an array

```
style={[styles.placeInput, {width: 300}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your placesOutput variable is returning an object as jsx.

Instead of

```
const placesOutput = this.state.places.map((place, i) => (
        <Text key={i}>{place}</Text>
         ));
```

Try

```
const placesOutput = this.state.places.map((place, i) => (
        <Text key={i}>{place.name} /* place is an object use any property of it. */</Text>
    ));
```

Comment: I used some random property to use as an example. You should use any property that place object might have. Try and see if it works.

Comment: yeah, it was an object, so silly of me ...its working fine now, thanks