# Why is React saying “Invalid prop `children`” types is object not function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem with prop-types. Warning message appear which said that `children` is object not a function.

But when I change that in object I have problem with npm Lint.

Which says that cannot be type of object.

How to avoid this issue?

Component code:

```
import propTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as React from 'react';

export default function layout({ children, title }) {
  return (
    <div className="root">

      <h2>{title}</h2>

      {children}

    </div>
  );
}

layout.propTypes = {
  children: propTypes.func.isRequired,
  title: propTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

**Warrning** message:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `object` supplied to `layout`, expected `function`.
>       in layout
>       in Index
>       in Container
>       in App
>       in Context.Provider
>       in Context.Provider
>       in Context.Provider
>       in Context.Provider

Comment: Probably duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child/51961113#51961113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The react children props is not a function its sort of an object.

try this:   children: PropTypes.element.isRequired