# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm getting this error:

> Error: **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {exRates}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Here is my React code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            exRates: []
        };
    }
    getCurrencyRatesFromDB = () => {
        fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest')
           .then((response) => {
             console.log('then 1', response);
            return response.json();                                                                     
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log('then 2', data);
            this.setState({
                exRates: data.rates
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log('render started');
        return (
            <div>
                console.log('return started')
                {this.state.exRates.map(rate => {
                   return <div>{rate.toString()}</div>
                 })}
                <button 
                    type="button" 
                    className="btn"
                    onClick={() => {
                        this.getCurrencyRatesFromDB();                                          
                    }}
                    >
                        Load rates
                </button>
                <p>{this.state}</p>
        </div>        
        )
    }
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

What do I need to do to handle it?

Comment: What are you attempting to render with this: `<p>{this.state}</p>` ?

Comment: Currency exchange rates from API.

Answer (score 2):

The object that is raising this error is `this.state` where you render it in a `p` tag near the end of your component.

As mentioned in the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child?rq=1), the only acceptable React children are [JavaScript Primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), e.g. strings and numbers. To render mutable things like objects and arrays, you have to give React some instructions for how to render them in terms of primitives, e.g. what to do with each element in an array or which keys in an object to put on the page.

You have the right idea rendering an array by mapping earlier in the component:

```
{this.state.exRates.map(rate => {
    return <div>{rate.toString()}</div>
})}
```

That will render everything in `exRates`, which it seems like is all you have in `this.state`. If you want to examine the actual object `this.state`, try putting `console.log(this.state)` in your render method but outside the `return`.

It's also worth mentioning that `console.log('return started')` is going to put that literal text onto the page.

**EDIT:** Here's how you can use `Object.entries` to get what it seems like you want here. Once you get the data you want in the second `.then` in `getCurrencyRatesFromDB`, instead of doing `this.setState({exRates: data.rates});` I would recommend doing `this.setState({exRates: Object.entries(data.rates)});`

That way, you will have an array of arrays which represents the data from your object. e.g. if you had `{usd: 10, eur: 12, gbp: 15}` in `data.rates`, you will end up with `[[usd, 10], [eur, 12], [gbp, 15]]` in `state.exRates`.

Then, in your `render` method, you can do the following code to render that information in your component:

```
{this.state.exRates.map(([currency, rate]) => <div>{`${currency}: ${rate}`}</div>)
```

That will give you HTML that looks something like this:

```
<div>usd: 10</div>
<div>eur: 12</div>
<div>gbp: 15</div>
```

Adjust capitalization as needed.

If the `...([currency, rate]) => ...` part of that threw you, that's [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and it's a very useful feature of modern JavaScript.

Comment: So React doesn't know what to do with it. How is that? Please explain.
Anyway, I tried deleting <p>{this.state}</p>. It then after pushing 'Load rates' button gave an error
TypeError: this.state.exRates.map is not a function. 
If I understood your post correctly I did the mapping through exRates correctly and that part needs no edition.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include some more detail about why React doesn't handle objects as children without further handling. 
As for your second question: That's telling you that the `.map` property on `this.state.exRates` isn't a function. From that we can assume that `exRates` isn't an array, and running your API call confirms that it is an object. Try looking into the `Object.keys` function for information on how to turn an object into an array you can map over.

Comment: That's weird. Google says that Object.key in fact returns the array of the given object's property names.
Would that be too much if I ask you to share the complete correct code with some explanations?

Comment: Apologies, `Object.entries` is probably what you want here, assuming you don't need this to work in Internet Explorer. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). I'll go ahead and give you an example of how to use it here.