# Using map on array of objects results in a errormessage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out why this simple code does not work, it feels like I have done exactly the same thing many times before without errors. What have I done wrong?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { MenuItem } from '../menu-item/menu-item.component'
import './directory.styles.scss'

export const Directory = () => {
    const sections = [
        {
          title: 'hats',
          imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/cvpntL1/hats.png',
          id: 1,
          linkUrl: 'shop/hats'
        },
        {
          title: 'jackets',
          imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/px2tCc3/jackets.png',
          id: 2,
          linkUrl: 'shop/jackets'
        },
        {
          title: 'sneakers',
          imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/0jqHpnp/sneakers.png',
          id: 3,
          linkUrl: 'shop/sneakers'
        },
        {
          title: 'womens',
          imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/GCCdy8t/womens.png',
          size: 'large',
          id: 4,
          linkUrl: 'shop/womens'
        },
        {
          title: 'mens',
          imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/R70vBrQ/men.png',
          size: 'large',
          id: 5,
          linkUrl: 'shop/mens'
        }
      ];

    return (
        <div className="directory-menu">
            {sections.map((title, imageUrl, id) => <MenuItem key={id} title={title} imageUrl={imageUrl}/>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Error Message:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {title, imageUrl, id, linkUrl}). If you meant to render a collection
>   of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not destructuring properly i.e.

```
.((title, imageUrl, id) =>
```

should be

```
.(({title, imageUrl, id}) =>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child), it's a common React error.

You could also try something like this

```
Object.entries(sections).map((x)=>
    return x.title;
})
```