# Objects are not valid as a React child (APIs, JSON)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot display a property of my JSON (DataUser.name.first)

```
`
    import React, {useEffect,useState}from 'react';
    import Article from '../components/Article';
    import '../styles/containers/Home.scss';

    const Home = () => {
      const [DataUser, setDataUser] = useState("Cargando");

      useEffect(() => {
        const Cargar = async () => {
          let respuesta = await fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/`);
          let respuestaJSON = await respuesta.json();
          setDataUser(respuestaJSON.results[0]);
        };
        Cargar();
      }, []);

      return (
        <>
          <div className='Home'>
            {console.log(DataUser.gender)} /*:)*/
            {console.log(DataUser.name.first)} /*:(*/
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };
    export default Home;

`
```

I'm trying to pass properties to a component in react, when I pass the cell number everything is ok. But when I try to pass the name I get an error.

My JSON 
    
      `"results": [
        {
         "gender": "male",
         "name": {
          "title": "Mr",
          "first": "Elliot",
          "last": "Thompson"
         },
        },
       ],`

I want to get the value that is inside name. The problem that I see is that we have an object inside another object. and not an array inside an object.

Comment: Why don't you pass `DataUser.name.first` (instead of `DataUser.name` which is an object and not a string) to `Article`?

Comment: yes: this is the JSON. I just want to get the data from (first)
"name": {
"title": "Mr",
"first": "Alex",
"last": "Blanco"
},

Comment: `<Article cell={DataUser.cell} name={DataUser.name.first}/>` ?

Comment: I add the component code "Articulo"

Comment: I think that the .map function does not work, because I only want the property (name.first)

Comment: duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your Article component, check how you handle *name* prop.

You should treat it as an object:

```
DataUser.name = {
  "title": "Miss",
  "first": "Zenóbia",
  "last": "da Paz"
}
```

Or you can also pass one of the keys: title, first, last

```
<Article cell={DataUser.cell} name={DataUser.name.first}/>
```

If you can't resolve this, attach the  component code.

Comment: I add the component code "Articulo"

Comment: ApiURL: https://randomuser.me/api/

Comment: // check DataUser object before render

if (!DataUser) {
    return null;
}