# I need to search data in an array according to filter and set start form index of 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to search data in an array according to filter so I am able to do it I am searching data according to name and id but in the backend in index 0 I am not getting and name and id only getting one number so when I search data I am getting an undefined error so what my task is I need to set filter to start searching from index 1 mean ignore index 0

coming data example from a backend

```
[
  2,
  {
    search_id: "10000107",
    name: "dev name",
    
  },
  {
    search_id: "10000106",
    name: "alberto",
   
  },
]
```

```
function handleSearch(term) {
    const dummy = props.new_alert_list.filter((item) =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(term)
    );
    const dummy1 = props.new_alert_list.filter((item) =>
      item.search_id.includes(term)
    );
    const no = parseInt(term);
    if (isNaN(no)) setItems(dummy);
    else setItems(dummy1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice the array from index 1 to create a new array to filter from.

```
function handleSearch(term) {
  const dummy = props.new_alert_list.slice(1).filter((item) =>
    item.name.toLowerCase().includes(term)
  );
  const dummy1 = props.new_alert_list.slice(1).filter((item) =>
    item.search_id.includes(term)
  );
  const no = parseInt(term);
  if (isNaN(no)) setItems(dummy);
  else setItems(dummy1);
}
```

Alternatively you could access the current index being iterated (*the second parameter to `filter`*) and add a condition for non-zero (i.e. truthy) indices.

```
function handleSearch(term) {
  const dummy = props.new_alert_list.filter((item, index) =>
    index && item.name.toLowerCase().includes(term)
  );
  const dummy1 = props.new_alert_list.filter((item, index) =>
    index && item.search_id.includes(term)
  );
  const no = parseInt(term);
  if (isNaN(no)) setItems(dummy);
  else setItems(dummy1);
}
```

If the first element is irrelevant in the frontend UI then perhaps you should clear it out before sending in props, or better yet, remove it before saving it into any local component state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could start from element at index 1, but I think you could also use `hasOwnProperty`. Something like:

```js
let data = [
  2,
  {
    id: "10000107",
    name: "dev name",
    
  },
  {
    id: "10000106",
    name: "alberto",
   
  },
]

data.filter(x => {
  if (x.hasOwnProperty("id") && x.hasOwnProperty("name")) {
     console.log(x.id, " ", x.name); // if object in array has id and name properties then do stuff...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just sniff out if the item in the iterator has the properties. If so, then filter

```
 function handleSearch(term) {
    setItems(props.new_alert_list
      .filter(item => 
         (typeof item === "object" && 
         (item.hasOwnProperty('name') && item.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())) 
         || 
         (item.hasOwnProperty('search_id') && item.search_id.includes(term)) 
      ));
  }
```

```js
let data = [
  2, {
    search_id: "10000107",
    name: "dev name",
  },
  {
    search_id: "10000106",
    name: "alberto",
  },
  {},
  {
    name: "Joe"
  }
]

let term = 'alberto';
let filtered = data.filter(item => (typeof item === "object" && (item.hasOwnProperty('name') && item.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())) || (item.hasOwnProperty('search_id') && item.search_id.includes(term))));
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: getting screen white after type any word

Comment: @devdeveloper Sorry about that. answer updated and snippet attached

Comment: again it's going white screen

Comment: Ok. you can see the snippet works. One thing was your sample code has`id` but your function has `search_id` - which is it?

Comment: ok, updated for that. Pls test... snippet seems to work fine...

Comment: Are there other anomolies besides a number? Do you have some `null` in there? I'll have to catch that if so

Comment: I am not able to see any null beside a number

Comment: ok. still getting no response? I did update my answer to have search_id...

Comment: i think i am getting this error after typing and word Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Comment: Can you show the setItems() function in your question?

Comment: ```function handleSearch(term) {
    setItems(props.new_alert_list
      .filter(item => (typeof item === "object" && (
         item.name.toLowerCase().includes(term) || 
         item.search_id.includes(term)
      ))));
  }```

Comment: Can you show the `setItems()` function in your question? That was the `handleSearch` which is what our answers are editing. Need to see `setItems` that is where the error is happening I think

Comment: ```useEffect(() => {
    console.log("@L1IS Alert List: ", props.new_alert_list);
    setItems([...props.new_alert_list]);
  }, [props.new_alert_list]);```

Comment: const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

Comment: maybe in the JSX... related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child

Comment: do you get an error line number? what is it in your code?

Comment: it's not coming in page it's coming in the console after typing any word

Comment: react-dom.development.js:13413 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {search_id, search_type, name, aliases, address, country, country_of_jurisdiction, date_of_birth, , gender,

Comment: If you look at that link I sent you, that error can be caused by your tryig to output non-strings (object or arrays) in your JSX output. Maybe if you set up a stackBlitz we could help. Though, your original question has been solved: how to avoid trying to filter the number.

Comment: what happen if name and search id is empty

Comment: ok, check out my revised answer + snippet. It covers a few different scenarios

Comment: I wish you the best of luck, but I've gotta go. If you feel this helped solve your question, please consider accepting as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.filter()` has a second parameter "index", which you can use.

For example:

```js
[1,2,3].filter((element, index) => { return index != 0 });
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

You can pass another parameter `index` in the `filter()`

```js
function handleSearch(term) {
  const dummy = props.new_alert_list.filter((item, index) =>
    index !== 0 ? item.name.toLowerCase().includes(term) : false
  );
  const dummy1 = props.new_alert_list.filter((item, index) =>
    index !== 0 ? item.search_id.includes(term) : false
  );
  const no = parseInt(term);
  if (isNaN(no)) setItems(dummy);
  else setItems(dummy1);
```

Comment: getting screen white after typeing any word

Comment: @devdeveloper, try console.log ```dummy``` and ```dummy1``` to see if the output is correct or not.

Comment: yeah in dummy i am getting console.log

Comment: @devdeveloper, Do you mean you get the correct output but you still see a blank page? Do you have any error?

Comment: yeah right not able to see any error on the page only getting a blank white page or getting dummy in console

Comment: @devdeveloper, If you get the correct output, it means the solution is working. You actually have a rendering issue in your react program. If you use your original program, would that still a blank page?