# NextJS error "objects are not valid as a react child" with getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I continuously get an error when going onto the page listed as code here. I have tried undoing changes and nothing seems to be working for me. The error says: "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, published_at, created_at, updated_at}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```js
import { GetWatch } from "../../../utils/functions/getWatch";
import { Header } from "../../../components/header";
import { Navbar } from "../../../components/navbar";
import Image from "next/image";
import { DetailBox } from "../../../components/catalog/detailBox";
import { HeadContent } from "../../../components/headContent";

export default function WatchPage({ watch }) {
    return (
        <>
            <HeadContent title={watch.name} description={`About ${watch.name}`} />
            <main>
                <Header />
                <Navbar />

                <div className="lg:mt-20 lg:mb-20 mb-4 w-full flex flex-col lg:justify-center">
                    <div className="flex flex-col items-center lg:flex-row lg:items-start">
                        <div className="lg:ml-20">
                            <Image
                                src={`${process.env.SERVER_URL}${watch.images[0].url}`}
                                alt=""
                                width={500}
                                height={500}
                                className="lg:rounded-md"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="lg:flex lg:flex-col text-center lg:ml-60 lg:mr-20">
                            <div className="text-3xl">{watch.name}</div>
                            <div className="text-xl font-light opacity-70">
                                - {watch.description} -
                            </div>
                            <div className="mt-4">{watch.about}</div>
                            <DetailBox watch={watch} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ query: { id } }) {
    const { data, error } = await GetWatch(id);

    if (error !== null) {
        return {
            notFound: true,
        };
    }

    if (data == null) {
        return {
            notFound: true,
        };
    }

    return { props: { watch: data } };
}
```

The data structure being returned from the API and being passed to the function via getServerSideProps looks like this:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test Watch",
    "description": "A test Watch ",
    "about": "A very good test watch",
    "series": "test",
    "model": "test",
    "gender": "male",
    "movement": "test",
    "engine": "test",
    "power_reserve": "test",
    "dial_type": "test",
    "dial_color": "test",
    "crystal": "test",
    "hands": "test",
    "bezel_material": "test",
    "crown": "test",
    "band_type": "test",
    "band_material": "test",
    "band_width": "test",
    "band_length": "test",
    "clasp": "test",
    "case_diameter": "test",
    "case_thickness": "test",
    "case_material": "test",
    "case_shape": "test",
    "case_back": "test",
    "water_resistance": "test",
    "functions": "test",
    "features": "test",
    "warranty": "test",
    "upc_code": "test",
    "sku": "test",
    "band_color": "test",
    "calendar": "test",
    "luminiscence": "test",
    "watch_label": "test",
    "product_category": "test",
    "watch_style": "test",
    "brand": {},
    "published_at": "2021-07-25T07:51:58.944Z",
    "created_at": "2021-07-25T07:38:26.842Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-07-28T07:37:52.136Z",
    "images": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "randomwatch.jpeg",
        "alternativeText": "",
        "caption": "",
        "width": 1000,
        "height": 667,
        "formats": {
            "thumbnail": {
                "name": "thumbnail_randomwatch.jpeg",
                "hash": "thumbnail_randomwatch_c7228f156b",
                "ext": ".jpeg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 234,
                "height": 156,
                "size": 10.9,
                "path": null,
                "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_randomwatch_c7228f156b.jpeg"
            },
            "medium": {
                "name": "medium_randomwatch.jpeg",
                "hash": "medium_randomwatch_c7228f156b",
                "ext": ".jpeg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 750,
                "height": 500,
                "size": 80,
                "path": null,
                "url": "/uploads/medium_randomwatch_c7228f156b.jpeg"
            },
            "small": {
                "name": "small_randomwatch.jpeg",
                "hash": "small_randomwatch_c7228f156b",
                "ext": ".jpeg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "width": 500,
                "height": 334,
                "size": 40.85,
                "path": null,
                "url": "/uploads/small_randomwatch_c7228f156b.jpeg"
            }
        },
        "hash": "randomwatch_c7228f156b",
        "ext": ".jpeg",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "size": 125.13,
        "url": "/uploads/randomwatch_c7228f156b.jpeg",
        "previewUrl": null,
        "provider": "local",
        "provider_metadata": null,
        "created_at": "2021-07-25T12:51:21.086Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-25T12:51:21.100Z"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to render `object` as a child of some component. Check out [this SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)

Everything seems to be fine in the `WatchPage` component, but notice, that you are passing the entire `watch` object to the `DetailBox`. Maybe there is an issue there?