# Objects are not valid as a React child when wrapping App in mobx RootStoreProvider

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Trying to get Mobx running with my react app. When I wrap the entire app in the `RootStoreProvider` I get the following error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` Whatever `children` is its not a react component and I can't quite figure out why (I am aware this issue is because children is an [object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child))... I am trying to follow several example tutorials [here](https://github.com/ivandotv/react-hooks-mobx-root-store) and [here](https://medium.com/@nazmifeeroz/how-to-use-react-usecontext-and-usestate-hooks-as-a-global-store-1b4f1898034f) which all seem to have the same function more or less:

```
export function RootStoreProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  // only create root store once (store is a singleton)
  const root = store ?? new RootStore();

  return <StoreContext.Provider value={root}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>;
}
```

Here is what my `index.tsx` file looks like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <RootStoreProvider>
        <App />
      </RootStoreProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Below I am including all my store/provider files:

RootStore.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import DeckStore from './DeckStore';

export default class RootStore {
  deckStore: DeckStore;

  constructor() {
    this.deckStore = DeckStore(this);
  }
}
```

DeckStore.tsx

```
import { RootStore } from './RootStore';
import { makeAutoObservable } from 'mobx';

const DeckStore = (root: RootStore) => {
  return makeAutoObservable({
    decks: [{
      title: 'somedeck'
    }],
    addDeck: (deck) => {
      root.deckStore.decks.push(deck);
    },
  });
}

export default DeckStore;
```

provider.tsx

```
import React, { createContext, ReactNode, useContext } from "react";
import RootStore from "../stores/RootStore";

let store: RootStore;
const StoreContext = createContext<RootStore | undefined>(undefined);
StoreContext.displayName = "StoreContext";

export function useRootStore() {
  const context = useContext(StoreContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useRootStore must be used within RootStoreProvider");
  }

  return context;
}

export const useDeckStore = () => {
  const { deckStore } = useRootStore();
  return deckStore;
}

export function RootStoreProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  // only create root store once (store is a singleton)
  const root = store ?? new RootStore();

  return <StoreContext.Provider value={root}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>;
}
```

Comment: How are you using this store? Maybe the problem is inside `App` component, have you tried to remove it to see if the error goes away?

Comment: I am not using it at all right now... I am just trying to integrate Mobx into my application and get it to load.  To answer your question, what I delete `<App />` it loads a blank page without any errors.

Comment: If you are not using the store then the problem is not inside the store obviously. Check your `App` component and all its children.