# How to add an anonymous object to a react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to set data from the backend to an object using react hook. The data from the backend cannot be the same structure always, so need to treat that as an Anonymous Object.

```
import axios from "axios";

function AppNew() {
  const [anonymousObject, setAnonymousObject] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios("https://example.com/GetData");
      setAnonymousObject(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return <div> {anonymousObject} </div>;
}
export default AppNew;
```

It ends up with the error

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. react-dom.development.js:13231
```

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: what is the structure of your object? what are you trying to do with it? please update your answer.

Comment: currently you're trying to just render an object in the DOM, which react doesn't allow you to do.

Comment: if perhaps you want to render the object's JSON structure, you can use `<div>{JSON.stringify(anonymousObject)}</div>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)

Comment: @szaman the structure of the object is anonymous, it can very. I can pass the data from the backend as a json string and temporary fix the issue, but it will be good if there any other solution exists.

Comment: @Nsevens
What you said is correct! I was thinking something wrong with the useState(), it was not.
The problem was in the UI rendering side.

The react cannot render the object directly on the UI.
```{JSON.stringify(anonymousObject)}``` this fixes the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to print an object to HTML. `{anonymousObject}` doesn't work. You should use `{JSON.stringify(anonymousObject)}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't mount any object in render. What you should do instead is to create a function which takes your object and return a component. Some king of a mapper function which takes some values from you object and create texts or whatever you want with them.